# How to read json with XmlReader

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json

Given a stream of JSON, how can I read it as XML.
I am aware of System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader but it is internal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered here:

[How to convert JSON to XML or XML to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/json-net-convert-json-string-to-xml-or-xml-to-json-string)

Answer (score 0):

Well, JSON isn't XML, so you can't read it as XML.  Might want to look into the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) though.