# Unix command-line JSON parser?

Tags: json, parsing, unix, configuration

Can anyone recommend a Unix (choose your flavor) JSON parser that could be used to introspect values from a JSON response in a pipeline?

Comment: I like to use pythonpy (https://github.com/russell91/pythonpy): cat a.json | py --ji -x 'x.attr'

Comment: Related: [Command line tool for parsing JSON input for Unix?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19018/3474) at SR

Comment: See also [Read the json data in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488315/read-the-json-data-in-shell-script)

Comment: There's a new tool in town: [ramda-cli](https://github.com/raine/ramda-cli), which uses Ramda's curried api and LiveScript terse syntax. It's built to take json as input and compose functions. `npm install -g ramda-cli`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618038

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use this command-line parser (which you could put into a bash alias if you like), using modules built into the Perl core:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -MJSON::PP=from_json -ne'print Dumper(from_json($_))'
```

Comment: I am confused by the output of this. The output includes fat arrows (=>) between keys and values. This isn't JSON.

Comment: @landon: no, the input is JSON, and the output is a native Perl data structure, which you can then go on to further manipulate if needed. The point of this one-liner is it produces data that is much easier to read.

Comment: If you want a JSON output, you can use this Perl one-liner: `perl -e "use JSON; print to_json( decode_json(<>), { pretty => 1 } )"`

Answer (score 235):

I prefer `python -m json.tool` which seems to be available per default on most *nix operating systems per default.

```
$ echo '{"foo":1, "bar":2}' | python -m json.tool
{
    "bar": 2, 
    "foo": 1
}
```

Note: **Depending on your version of python**, all keys might get sorted alphabetically, which can or can not be a good thing. With python 2 it was the default to sort the keys, while in python 3.5+ they are no longer sorted automatically, but you have the option to sort by key explicitly:

```
$ echo '{"foo":1, "bar":2}' | python3 -m json.tool --sort-keys
{
    "bar": 2, 
    "foo": 1
}
```

Comment: Underrated answer. This is a nice command-line alternative if the goal is to validate a given JSON file as containing valid JSON.

Comment: this answer didn't describe how to inspect values of specified key.

Comment: @ColinSu but that was also not the original question. `json.tool` is just a short hand to pretty print json. If you need to extract/manipulate json data in a shell script, I would use `jq` which is pure awesome at what is does...

Comment: @muhqu yeah, I know, I use `json.tool` ten times daily. I think I misread the meaning of "introspec" in the question, thank for your pointing out.

Comment: IMMO this is an incorrect answer because python's `json.tool` only does two things: validate and pretty-print json. It does NOT introspect values in the json like `jq` does.

Comment: For Python 3.5+, the keys are not sorted automatically but rather follow the same order as the input. One needs to use the `--sort-keys` option to have the keys sorted.

Comment: @AdityaSriram good to know! …will add this info to the answer.

Answer (score 149):

If you're looking for a portable C compiled tool:

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

From the website:

> jq is like *sed* for JSON data - you can use it to slice and filter and map and transform structured data with the same ease that *sed*, *awk*, *grep* and friends let you play with text.
>
> jq can mangle the data format that you have into the one that you want with very little effort, and the program to do so is often shorter and simpler than you’d expect.

**Tutorial**: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/
**Manual**: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/
**Download**: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

Comment: Best answer in here imo. No heavy dependencies, small, powerful, good documentation and a breeze to try it out. Thanks a lot for suggesting this!

Comment: On Ubuntu/Debian you can just `apt install jq`.

Comment: I asked this many-a-moon ago, and have learned to love `jq`.

Answer (score 62):

I have created a module specifically designed for command-line JSON manipulation:

https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli

- **FLEXIBLE** - THE "swiss-army-knife" tool for processing JSON data - can be used as a simple pretty-printer, or as a full-powered Javascript command-line
- **POWERFUL** - Exposes the full power and functionality of underscore.js (plus underscore.string)
- **SIMPLE** - Makes it simple to write JS one-liners similar to using "perl -pe"
- **CHAINED** - Multiple command invokations can be chained together to create a data processing pipeline
- **MULTI-FORMAT** - Rich support for input / output formats - pretty-printing, strict JSON, etc [coming soon]
- **DOCUMENTED** - Excellent command-line documentation with multiple examples for every command

It allows you to do powerful things really easily:

```
cat earthporn.json | underscore select '.data .title'
# [ 'Fjaðrárgljúfur canyon, Iceland [OC] [683x1024]',
#   'New town, Edinburgh, Scotland [4320 x 3240]',
#   'Sunrise in Bryce Canyon, UT [1120x700] [OC]',
# ...
#   'Kariega Game Reserve, South Africa [3584x2688]',
#   'Valle de la Luna, Chile [OS] [1024x683]',
#   'Frosted trees after a snowstorm in Laax, Switzerland [OC] [1072x712]' ]

cat earthporn.json | underscore select '.data .title' | underscore count
# 25

underscore map --data '[1, 2, 3, 4]' 'value+1'
# prints: [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

underscore map --data '{"a": [1, 4], "b": [2, 8]}' '_.max(value)'
# [ 4, 8 ]

echo '{"foo":1, "bar":2}' | underscore map -q 'console.log("key = ", key)'
# key = foo
# key = bar

underscore pluck --data "[{name : 'moe', age : 40}, {name : 'larry', age : 50}, {name : 'curly', age : 60}]" name
# [ 'moe', 'larry', 'curly' ]

underscore keys --data '{name : "larry", age : 50}'
# [ 'name', 'age' ]

underscore reduce --data '[1, 2, 3, 4]' 'total+value'
# 10
```

And it has one of the best "smart-whitespace" JSON formatters available:

[image]

If you have any feature requests, comment on this post or add an issue in github.  I'd be glad to prioritize features that are needed by members of the community.

Comment: Awesome! But, is it possible to run console commands on JSON data? For example: given a JSON file with an URL array, `wget` every URL.

Comment: @CamiloMartin - the easiest way to do that is to print out the URLs, one URL per line, and then run that through xargs or GNU parallel.

Comment: @DaveDopson Can I use `underscore` for parsing nested json having nested objects and arrays?

Comment: @user227666 - sure.  JSON supports nesting many levels of objects.  Or you might mean JSON that has a string which encodes further JSON.  Which also works, but requires just a bit of munging.

Comment: @DaveDopson Does underscore support "contains" a "pattern", ie. for a specific "key", the possible set of (case-insenstitive) values ?  I tried "jq" with match, but it doesn't work. Also posted my complete use-case here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463196/filtering-by-value-in-jq-while-building-regex-patterns

Answer (score 14):

There is also [JSON command line processing toolkit](http://github.com/zpoley/json-command) if you happen to have node.js and npm in your stack.

And another ["json" command](https://github.com/trentm/json) for massaging JSON on your Unix command line.

And here are the other alternatives:

- jq: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/
- fx: https://github.com/antonmedv/fx
- json:select: https://github.com/dominictarr/json-select
- json-command: https://github.com/zpoley/json-command
- JSONPath: http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/, http://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/wiki/Javascript
- jsawk: https://github.com/micha/jsawk
- jshon: http://kmkeen.com/jshon/
- json2: https://github.com/vi/json2

---

Related: [Command line tool for parsing JSON input for Unix?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19018)

Comment: Easy to install, on Ubuntu:  sudo apt-get install python-pip && sudo pip install jsonpipe

Comment: @divideandconquer.se Sorry but you install this tool using npm with `npm install json`.

Comment: @rednaw Unfortunately, the NPM package `json` seems to be taken over by a completely different package now.

Answer (score 14):

Checkout [TickTick](https://github.com/kristopolous/TickTick).

It's a true Bash JSON parser.

```
#!/bin/bash
. /path/to/ticktick.sh

# File
DATA=`cat data.json`
# cURL
#DATA=`curl http://foobar3000.com/echo/request.json`

tickParse "$DATA"

echo ``pathname``
echo ``headers["user-agent"]``
```

Comment: Gotta love shell-level tools :)

Answer (score 8):

Anyone mentioned Jshon or JSON.sh?

https://github.com/keenerd/jshon

pipe json to it, and it traverses the json objects and prints out the path to the current object (as a JSON array) and then the object, without whitespace.

http://kmkeen.com/jshon/
Jshon loads json text from stdin, performs actions, then displays the last action on stdout and also was made to be part of the usual text processing pipeline.

Comment: Example usage on OSX: `brew install jshon`, `cat *.json | jshon`

Answer (score 2):

You could try [jsawk](http://github.com/micha/jsawk) as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk/1955555#1955555).

Really you could whip up a quick python script to do this though.

Answer (score 1):

For **Bash/Python**, here is a basic wrapper around python's `simplejson`:

```
json_parser() {
    local jsonfile="my_json_file.json"
    local tc="import simplejson,sys; myjsonstr=sys.stdin.read(); "`
            `"myjson=simplejson.loads(myjsonstr);"
    # Build python print command based on $@
    local printcmd="print myjson"
    for (( argn=1; argn<=$#; argn++ )); do
        printcmd="$printcmd['${!argn}']"
    done
    local result=$(python -c "$tc $printcmd.keys()" <$jsonfile 2>/dev/null \
        || python -c "$tc $printcmd" <$jsonfile 2>/dev/null)
    # For returning space-separated values
    echo $result|sed -e "s/[]|[|,|']//g"
    #echo $result 
}
```

It really only handles the nested-dictionary style of data, but it works for what I needed, and is useful for walking through the json.  It could probably be adapted to taste.

Anyway, something homegrown for those not wanting to source in yet another external dependency.  Except for python, of course.

Ex. `json_parser {field1} {field2}` would run `print myjson['{field1}']['{field2}']`, yielding either the keys or the values associated with `{field2}`, space-separated.

Answer (score 0):

I just made [jkid](http://github.com/arthurprat/jkid) which is a small command-line json explorer that I made to easily explore big json objects. Objects can be explored "transversally" and a "preview" option is there to avoid console overflow.

```
$  echo '{"john":{"size":20, "eyes":"green"}, "bob":{"size":30, "eyes":"brown"}}' > test3.json
$  jkid . eyes test3.json 
object[.]["eyes"]
{
  "bob": "brown", 
  "john": "green"
}
```

Comment: How can I install `jkid` in mac?