# JSON config to bash variables

Tags: json, bash, configuration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unix command-line JSON parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858671/unix-command-line-json-parser)

If I have a config file in JSON and a PHP script to flatten the config file into something like this

```
database_dbname=sensei
database_password=somerandompassword
memcached_host=localhost
....
```

can I pipe this to my bash script and make each of the entry above as a variable?

```
./bin/flatten_config.php config.json | ./bin/my_bash_script.sh
```

so that in my bash-script I can use values from the config file

```
mysql -D${database_dbname} -p${database_password} ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `bash` you could write in your script-file

```
source <(./bin/flatten_config.php config.json)
```

`bash` will take the output of `flatten_config.php` and parse it like input

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Not sure about brackets though.

Comment: not sure about the bracket, but thanks for the clue :) just found out a bit more on source command here http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/54347-bash-shell-exec-eval-source-looking-help-understand.html

Comment: +1. the parentheses are correct: this is [bash process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)

Comment: If you don't have Bash, or want to be portable, try with `eval` and backticks.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [TickTick](https://github.com/kristopolous/TickTick).

It's a true Bash JSON parser.

```
#!/bin/bash
. /path/to/ticktick.sh

# File
DATA=`cat data.json`
# cURL
#DATA=`curl http://foobar3000.com/echo/request.json`

tickParse "$DATA"

echo ``pathname``
echo ``headers["user-agent"]``
```