# Get complete json tag content by a matching pattern with Regex tools

Tags: regex, json, perl, sed, awk

I have a json file which has 3 items listed in it as so:

```
{
Item 1
lots of stuff
more stuff 1545
even more
},
{
Item 2
lots of stuff
more stuff 542
},
{
Item 2
lots of stuff
more stuff 675
even more
more words
more text
}
```

I want to be able to grep for a string say 675 and if it finds that to return the entire 'block' of text, from the opening to closing brackets.

Comment: You can correct formatted json files parse with a `json parser`. but your example is **not** correct formatted.

Comment: Take a look at some command-line json parsers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858671/unix-command-line-json-parser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU sed parser for your irregular file format (put your search pattern at position `PATTERN`):

```
sed -nr 'H;/PATTERN/,/\}/{s/(\})/\1/;T;x;p};/\{/{x;s/.*\n.*//;x;H}' file
```

- and some examples:

```
$sed -nr 'H;/1545/,/\}/{s/(\})/\1/;T;x;p};/\{/{x;s/.*\n.*//;x;H}' file

{
Item 1
lots of stuff
more stuff 1545
even more
},

$sed -nr 'H;/542/,/\}/{s/(\})/\1/;T;x;p};/\{/{x;s/.*\n.*//;x;H}' file

{
Item 2
lots of stuff
more stuff 542
},

$sed -nr 'H;/more text/,/\}/{s/(\})/\1/;T;x;p};/\{/{x;s/.*\n.*//;x;H}' file

{
Item 3
lots of stuff
more stuff 675
even more
more words
more text
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If by "grep for a string" you really mean search for an RE like you normally would with grep, then:

```
awk -v t="675" -v ORS= '{r=r $0 RS} /^}/{if (r~t) print r; r=""}' file
```

but if you truly mean search for a string like you would with fgrep then:

```
awk -v t="675" -v ORS= '{r=r $0 RS} /^}/{if (index(r,t)) print r; r=""}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done with `grep` and shouldn't be done with `bash` but it's quite simple if you have `GNU awk` just define `RS` as `},?\n`:

```
# find a record containing 1545
$ awk '/1545/' RS='},?\n' ORS='}\n' file
{
Item 1
lots of stuff
more stuff 1545
even more
}
```

This method won't separate multiple records with a `,` like `JSON` should but you could define `ORS` as `},` and remove the last `,` if you need valid `JSON` as the result.

Alternatively you could also use `RT` instead of `ORS` to display the separator that matched the `RS` regexp:

```
$ awk '/1545/{printf "%s",$0RT}' RS='},?\n' file
{
Item 1
lots of stuff
more stuff 1545
even more
},
```

But depending on whether the last record matched the given pattern you might still need to remove the trailing `,`. A simple `sed` command would do the trick `sed '$s/,$//'`.

I'd probably just use a proper `JSON` passer however.

Comment: +1 for a good solution. I don't know "JSON" but if `}` can occur at the end of a line elsewhere in the block of text then you need to put a `\n` before it in the RS. Of the 2 solutions you proposed, I'd definitely use the RT one since you're using GNU awk anyway to get multi-char RS.