# How to extract data from a JSON object in Bash?

Tags: json, bash, shell

I've captured the below command output in a Bash variable:

> `{"app_versions":[{"version":"16125","shortversion":"4.4.0","title":"App 1","timestamp":1377277516,"appsize":46110031,"mandatory":false,"minimum_os_version":"6.0","device_family":"iPhone/iPod","id":22,"app_id":25196,"download_url":"https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/b5dc72777668ca5716aa6aec8237058f/app_versions/22","status":2,"tags":["alpha"]},{"version":"16126","shortversion":"4.4.0","title":"App 1","timestamp":1377177516,"appsize":46330031,"mandatory":false,"minimum_os_version":"6.0","device_family":"iPhone/iPod","id":20,"app_id":25190,"download_url":"https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/b5dc72777668ca5716aa6aec8237058f/app_versions/20","status":2,"tags":["alpha"]}`

How can I find the highest value of `id` from the above output and get the associated `version`?

Comment: Which "shell" in which operating system?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response. I am using Bash in Mac OS.

Comment: I've edited your question to mention JSON explicitly. If you didn't realize that this output was in JSON format, then I recommend you Google 'JSON' to learn about the format (and associated tools).

Comment: Thank you ruakh. i will google to find the answer but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can any one help me with this please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unix command-line JSON parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858671/unix-command-line-json-parser)

Answer (score 1):

The value that you've posted is not valid JSON — it's missing a few characters at the end — but assuming that your actual value *is* valid, you can write something like this:

```
perl -e \
  ' use warnings;
    use strict;
    use JSON ();
    my $highest_id;
    my $version;
    foreach my $app_version (@{(JSON::from_json $ARGV[0])->{"app_versions"}}) {
        my $id = $app_version->{"id"};
        if(! defined ($highest_id) || $id > $highest_id) {
            $highest_id = $id;
            $version = $app_version->{"version"};
        }
    }
    print $version;
  ' \
  "$your_variable"
```