# Parsing Json data columnwise in shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

When I run a command I get a response like this

```
{

    "status": "available",
    "managed": true,
    "name":vdisk7,
    "support":{
    "status": "supported"
    },
    "storage_pool": "pfm9253_pfm9254_new",
    "id": "ff10abad"-2bf-4ef3-9038-9ae7f18ea77c",
    "size":100
},
```

and hundreds of this type of lists or dictionaries
I want a command that does such sort of a thing

```
if name = "something", 
    get the id
```

Any links that would help me in learning such sort of commands would be highly appreciated

I have tried

awk '{if ($2 == "something") print $0;}'

But I think the response is in Json so the colum wise awk formatting is not working.

Also it's just a single command that I need to run so I would prefer not to use any external library.

Comment: Have you looked at [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) ?  It has a convenient syntax for filtering.

Comment: See also [Unix command-line JSON parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858671/unix-command-line-json-parser)

Comment: For AWK-based JSON parsing see [JSON.awk](https://github.com/step-/JSON.awk)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**JSON parser is better for this task**

`awk` and `sed` are utilities to parse line-oriented text, but not json. What if your json formatting will change ? (some lines will go on one line ?).

You should use any standard json parser out there. Or use some powerful scripting language, such as PHP, Python, Ruby, etc.

I can provide you with example on how to do it with python.

**What if I can't use powerful scripting language ?**

If you totally unable to use python, then there is utility `jq` out there: [link](http://xmodulo.com/2013/05/how-to-parse-json-string-via-command-line-on-linux.html)

If you have some recent distro, `jq` maybe already in repositories (example: Ubuntu 13.10 has it in repos).

**I can use python!**

I would do that using simple python inline script.

For example we have some `some_command` that returns json as a result.

We have to get value of `data["name"]`.

Here we go:

```
some_command | python -c "import json, sys; print json.load(sys.stdin)['name']"
```

It will output `vdisk7` in your case

For this to work you need to be sure, json is fully valid.

If you have a list of json objects:

```
[
  {
    ...
    "name": "vdisk17"
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    "name": "vdisk18"
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    "name": "vdisk19"
    ...
  },
...
]
```

You could use some list comprehensions:

```
some_command | python -c "import json, sys; [sys.stdout.write(x['name'] + '\n') for x in json.load(sys.stdin)]"
```

It will output:

```
vdisk17
vdisk18
vdisk19
```

Comment: That works. But I am not allowed to use Python, simple bash commands like awk, grep , sed, head , tail , you get the idea.

Comment: What limits you from using python ? Python is in LSB (linux standard base). So it should be available on every linux distro.

Comment: @Waterlink 
Would that work in AIX too ??I can't test on AIX right now but I might need to do that in a few days.

Comment: @MAD_ABOUT_JAVA I got your problem here. Then you totally unable to use python ) You can try to build jq from source.

Comment: Yes, that's better. Thanx for the help Waterlink.