# Read JSON data in a shell script

Tags: json, bash, shell

In shell I have a requirement wherein I have to read the JSON response which is in the following format:

```
 { "Messages": [ { "Body": "172.16.1.42|/home/480/1234/5-12-2013/1234.toSort", "ReceiptHandle": "uUk89DYFzt1VAHtMW2iz0VSiDcGHY+H6WtTgcTSgBiFbpFUg5lythf+wQdWluzCoBziie8BiS2GFQVoRjQQfOx3R5jUASxDz7SmoCI5bNPJkWqU8ola+OYBIYNuCP1fYweKl1BOFUF+o2g7xLSIEkrdvLDAhYvHzfPb4QNgOSuN1JGG1GcZehvW3Q/9jq3vjYVIFz3Ho7blCUuWYhGFrpsBn5HWoRYE5VF5Bxc/zO6dPT0n4wRAd3hUEqF3WWeTMlWyTJp1KoMyX7Z8IXH4hKURGjdBQ0PwlSDF2cBYkBUA=", "MD5OfBody": "53e90dc3fa8afa3452c671080569642e", "MessageId": "e93e9238-f9f8-4bf4-bf5b-9a0cae8a0ebc" } ] }
```

Here I am only concerned with the "Body" property value. I made some unsuccessful attempts like:

```
 jsawk -a 'return this.Body'
```

or

```
 awk -v k="Body" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}
```

But that did not suffice. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: No that is not the option in this case. But for the knowledge purpose please post your comment if you do not mind.

Comment: It is generally not good idea to parse json format with shell oriented tools, see this link for more ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511851/parsing-json-data-columnwise-in-shell

Comment: See also [Unix command-line JSON parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858671/unix-command-line-json-parser)

Comment: Are external tools an option? http://kmkeen.com/jshon/

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There is `jq` for parsing json on the command line:

```
 jq '.Body'
```

Visit this for jq: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: In case you found this and need it for another platform: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

Answer (score 16):

### tl;dr

```
$ cat /tmp/so.json | underscore select '.Messages .Body' 
["172.16.1.42|/home/480/1234/5-12-2013/1234.toSort"]
```

### Javascript CLI tools

You can use Javascript CLI tools like

- [underscore-cli](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli):
- [json:select()](http://jsonselect.org/): CSS-like selectors for JSON.

#### Example

Select all `name` children of a `addons`:

```
underscore select ".addons > .name"
```

The `underscore-cli` provide others [real world examples](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli#real-world-examples) as well as the [json:select() doc](http://jsonselect.org/#tryit).

Answer (score 6):

Similarly using Bash regexp. Shall be able to snatch any key/value pair.

```
key="Body"
re="\"($key)\": \"([^\"]*)\""

while read -r l; do
    if [[ $l =~ $re ]]; then
        name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        value="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        echo "$name=$value"
    else
        echo "No match"
    fi
done
```

Regular expression can be tuned to match multiple spaces/tabs or newline(s). Wouldn't work if value has embedded `"`. This is an illustration. Better to use some "industrial" parser :)

Comment: This does not work for every possible key/value pair. Consider `"key": "value \"with quotes\""`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a crude way to do it:  Transform JSON into `bash` variables to `eval` them.

This only works for:

- JSON which does not contain nested arrays, and
- JSON from trustworthy sources (else it may confuse your shell script, perhaps it may even be able to harm your system, **You have been warned**)

Well, yes, it uses PERL to do this job, thanks to CPAN, but is small enough for inclusion directly into a script and hence is quick and easy to debug:

```
json2bash() {
perl -MJSON -0777 -n -E 'sub J {
my ($p,$v) = @_; my $r = ref $v;
if ($r eq "HASH") { J("${p}_$_", $v->{$_}) for keys %$v; }
elsif ($r eq "ARRAY") { $n = 0; J("$p"."[".$n++."]", $_) foreach @$v; }
else { $v =~ '"s/'/'\\\\''/g"'; $p =~ s/^([^[]*)\[([0-9]*)\](.+)$/$1$3\[$2\]/;
$p =~ tr/-/_/; $p =~ tr/A-Za-z0-9_[]//cd; say "$p='\''$v'\'';"; }
}; J("json", decode_json($_));'
}
```

use it like `eval "$(json2bash <<<'{"a":["b","c"]}')"`

Not heavily tested, though.  Updates, warnings and more examples see my [GIST](https://gist.github.com/hilbix/c75ac2a63758dc8410d7).

## Update

(Unfortunately, following is a link-only-solution, as the C code is far
too long to duplicate here.)

For all those, who do not like the above solution,
there now is a [C program json2sh](https://github.com/hilbix/json2sh)
which (hopefully safely) converts JSON into shell variables.
In contrast to the `perl` snippet, it is able to process any JSON,
as long as it is well formed.

Caveats:

- `json2sh` was not tested much.
- `json2sh` may create variables, which start with the shellshock pattern `() {`

I wrote `json2sh` to be able to post-process `.bson` with Shell:

```
bson2json()
{
printf '[';
{ bsondump "$1"; echo "\"END$?\""; } | sed '/^{/s/$/,/';
echo ']';
};

bsons2json()
{
printf '{';
c='';
for a;
do
  printf '%s"%q":' "$c" "$a";
  c=',';
  bson2json "$a";
done;
echo '}';
};

bsons2json */*.bson | json2sh | ..
```

Explained:

- `bson2json` dumps a `.bson` file such, that the records become a JSON array

  - If everything works OK, an `END0`-Marker is applied, else you will see something like `END1`.
  - The `END`-Marker is needed, else empty `.bson` files would not show up.
- `bsons2json` dumps a bunch of `.bson` files as an object, where the output of `bson2json` is indexed by the filename.

This then is postprocessed by `json2sh`, such that you can use `grep`/`source`/`eval`/etc. what you need, to bring the values into the shell.

This way you can quickly process the contents of a MongoDB dump on shell level, without need to import it into MongoDB first.

Comment: To the downvoter: What's wrong with my answer?  `eval` is not evil in this context.  And my answer explains how to access JSON in Shell and Perl.  If applied to the JSON-string from the question the wanted result can be found in `${json_Messages_Body[0]}`, just try it, it's just too obvious.  And if you downvote because of my warning, well, shoot the messenger, but this still does not change the fact that my warning is true for most shell scripts. **Those, who can write safe scripts, usually do not need to ask on stackoverflow.**  So the warning apparently is needed here.

Comment: I've been using Perl since 1992, and the code here is *not* immediately obvious to me. You say it is safe, but I don't think that's necessarily true just because you say so. JSON parsers which were not written specifically with security in mind have been responsible for nasty security bugs in the past.  If this *was* written with security in mind, please document that in more detail, with credible sources.

Comment: @tripleee: I do **not claim it is safe**.  This is clearly stated in the text: "This only works for .. JSON **from trustworthy sources**".  (Added "and" now to make it more clear). For example it is **not hardened against shell-shock** and you will see strange errors in case JSON contains nested arrays.  If you are puzzled what it does, just run `jsonsource | json2bash`, as it outputs the shell code to stdout.  Please note that this code certainly can be improved to create something which can be considered more safe.  Doing it safely means a lot more effort than presented here.

Comment: You are saying that  `eval` is not evil, which implies to me that you consider this safe to use.

Comment: In a trustworthy context `eval` is not evil.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because the code looks like a cat walked over my keyboard. Unmaintainable.

Comment: Thanks for your honest words.  However when I expand it, then people might downvote, because it gets too lengthy to be used, so they have to minify itself.  My recommendation is, expand it yourself, such that you get a feeling for it.  Also I think that longer perl script are always a maintainance nightmare, because they look like some [cats had a party on the keyboard](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mithaldu/2011/10/perl-tutorials-suck-and-cause-serious-damage.html) .. (sorry for that pun) ;)