# Extract data from JSON file using bash

Tags: json, bash, shell

Let's say that we have this kind of JSON file:

```
{
  ... 
  "quotes":{
     "SOMETHING":10,
     ...
     "SOMETHING_ELSE":120.4,
     ...
  }   }
```

How can I obtain those values and use them in order to add them together?

Am I able to do even this?

```
#!/bin/bash

#code ...

echo "$SOMETHING + $SOMETHING_ELSE" | bc

#code ...

#exit
```

I will obtain the JSON file with wget command. All I want is the content from this file.

Can you help me, please? I am a beginner in shell programming.

Comment: @JoshJolly No, this is not one I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

I usually use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), a really fast json parser, to do this kind of things (because parsing a json file with tools like `awk` or `sed` is really error-prone).

Given an input file like this:

```
# file: input.json
{
  "quotes":{
    "SOMETHING":10,
    "SOMETHING_ELSE":120.4
  }
}
```

You can obtain the sum of the 2 fields with a simple filter:

```
jq '.quotes.SOMETHING + .quotes.SOMETHING_ELSE' input.json
# output -> 130.4
```

*NOTE*: `jq` is available in every major linux distribution. In a debian-derivative system you can install with a `sudo apt-get install jq`.

Answer (score 1):

This will print out the sum of the selected lines' floats.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{ if ($1 ~ /"SOMETHING":/) {print}; if ($1 ~ /"SOMETHING_ELSE":/) {print} }' $1 | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d, -f1 | awk '{s+=$1};END{print s}'
```

This finds the lines you want, the plucks out the numbers, and adds them.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up and learn `jq` as shown in [Read the json data in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488315/read-the-json-data-in-shell-script).

The tools in a "normal" shell installation like awk and sed all predate JSON by decades, and are a very very bad fit.  `jq` is worth the time to learn.

Or use Python instead.