# Find the value of key from JSON

Tags: json, grep

I'd like to extract the `"id"` key from this single line of JSON.

I believe this can be accomplished with grep, but I am not sure on the correct way.

If there is a better way that does not have dependencies, I would be interested.

Here is my example output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "test",
    "id": "4dCYd4W9i6gHQHvd",
    "domains": ["www.test.domain.com", "test.domain.com"],
    "serverid": "bbBdbbHF8PajW221",
    "ssl": null,
    "runtime": "php5.6",
    "sysuserid": "4gm4K3lUerbSPfxz",
    "datecreated": 1474597357
  },
  "actionid": "WXVAAHQDCSILMYTV"
}
```

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools

Comment: try `grep -o -P '"id":.*?",' json.file |sed 's/"\|,//g'` , should help you ..but it would be better if you would go for some json aware tools.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Shouldn't the `data:`'s contents be enclosed within `[ ]` ?

Comment: You can look for some Q&A : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488315/read-the-json-data-in-shell-script, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121718/how-to-parse-json-with-shell-scripting-in-linux

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If you have a grep that can do Perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE):

```
$ grep -Po '"id": *\K"[^"]*"' infile.json
"4dCYd4W9i6gHQHvd"
```

- `-P` enables PCRE
- `-o` retains nothing but the match
- `"id": *` matches `"id"` and an arbitrary amount of spaces
- `\K` throws away everything to its left ("variable size positive look-behind")
- `"[^"]*"` matches two quotes and all the non-quotes between them

If your grep can't do that, you an use

```
$ grep -o '"id": *"[^"]*"' infile.json | grep -o '"[^"]*"$'
"4dCYd4W9i6gHQHvd"
```

This uses grep twice. The result of the first command is `"id": "4dCYd4W9i6gHQHvd"`; the second command removes everything but a pair of quotes and the non-quotes between them, anchored at the end of the string (`$`).

But, as pointed out, you shouldn't use grep for this, but a tool that can parse JSON – for example [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ jq '.data.id' infile.json
"4dCYd4W9i6gHQHvd"
```

This is just a simple filter for the `id` key in the `data` object. To get rid of the double quotes, you can use the `-r` ("raw output") option:

```
$ jq -r '.data.id' infile.json
4dCYd4W9i6gHQHvd
```

jq can also neatly pretty print your JSON:

```
$ jq . infile.json
{
  "data": {
    "name": "test",
    "id": "4dCYd4W9i6gHQHvd",
    "domains": [
      "www.test.domain.com",
      "test.domain.com"
    ],
    "serverid": "bbBdbbHF8PajW221",
    "ssl": null,
    "runtime": "php5.6",
    "sysuserid": "4gm4K3lUerbSPfxz",
    "datecreated": 1474597357
  },
  "actionid": "WXVAAHQDCSILMYTV"
}
```

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks! Using grep will work perfect for this situation.  This works `grep -o '"id": *"[^"]*"' test.txt | grep -o '"[^"]*"$'`  How would I remove the quotes as well, leaving only the ID?

Comment: @petebocken You'd have to remove the last quote from the first command and the first and last quote from the second one: `grep -o '"id": *"[^"]*' test.txt | grep -o '[^"]*$'`

Comment: @BenjaminW. I tried several edits and for some reason couldn't find the right one to remove.  This works perfect, thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminW.  `'"id": *\K"[^"]*"'` this works for me, but how can i make sure i remove the double quotes from the result.

Comment: @SalilLambay You should use `jq -r` instead of grep, or you have to pipe to another instance of grep.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I tried the 2 grep solution and it worked :) cheers

Comment: @BenjaminW. This did what I needed without the quotes in the return, and making sure that escaped quotes are handled `"id": *"\K(?:\\"|[^"]))`. Still would need to handle escapes after you get it back, likely with `sed`. Play with my example: https://regex101.com/r/Lc9k5p/1

Comment: @BenjaminW. Sadly this needed to be done without installing more software on the systems, and a more robust programming language, like python, wouldn't be consistently available.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BenjaminW. This grep porn saved my several hours of manual effort. Works well with Mac Catalina's native grep!

Answer (score 10):

## Just pipe your data to `jq` and select by keys

```
"data": {
    "name": "test",
    "id": "4dCYd4W9i6gHQHvd",
    "domains": [
      "www.test.domain.com",
      "test.domain.com"
    ],
    "serverid": "bbBdbbHF8PajW221",
    "ssl": null,
    "runtime": "php5.6",
    "sysuserid": "4gm4K3lUerbSPfxz",
    "datecreated": 1474597357
  },
  "actionid": "WXVAAHQDCSILMYTV"
} | jq '.data.id'     

# 4dCYd4W9i6gHQHvd
```

## [Tutorial Here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/)

Answer (score 8):

I found myself that the best way is to use python, as it handles JSON natively and is preinstalled on most systems these days, unlike jq:

```
$ python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["data"]["id"])' < infile.json
4dCYd4W9i6gHQHvd
```

Comment: Liking this answer because it uses what is there. It's all too easy to just go installing more and more to solve things like this. Very simple, but overlooked approach!

Comment: best and easy solution

Comment: This can also be piped from `curl` request like so: `curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["title"])'` and it works for both python v2 & v3.

Answer (score 5):

No `python` ,`jq`, `awk`, `sed` just GNU `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
json='{"data": {"name": "test", "id": "4dCYd4W9i6gHQHvd", "domains": ["www.test.domain.com", "test.domain.com"], "serverid": "bbBdbbHF8PajW221", "ssl": null, "runtime": "php5.6", "sysuserid": "4gm4K3lUerbSPfxz", "datecreated": 1474597357}, "actionid": "WXVAAHQDCSILMYTV"}' 
        
echo $json | grep -o '"id": "[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$'
```

Tested & working here:  https://ideone.com/EG7fv7

source: https://brianchildress.co/parse-json-using-grep

Comment: It works, however the only issue comes when piping the output of `curl` to `grep`, since `curl` uses the stderr instead of stdout to output the results, we must pipe from the stderr (using `2>&1`) like so:`curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 2>&1 | grep -o '"title": "[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$'`.

Answer (score 0):

$ `grep -oP '"id": *"\K[^"]*' infile.json`

> 4dCYd4W9i6gHQHvd

*Hopefully it will work for all. As this will work for me to print without quotes.*