# read a json file using shell scipt

Tags: shell

I have the following data in a file -

```
{"a" : "10", "b" : "20", "c" : "30"}
```

When I read values in this variable -

`` eval "_value_=\"`cat hello1`\"" ``

`echo $_value_` equals `{a : 10, b : 20, c : 30}`

I can't read this using `jq -r`. Is there any way I can read double quotes in *value* as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488315/read-the-json-data-in-shell-script

Comment: This is a different question. I want the double quotes while reading the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not certain what you mean, but it sounds like your file `hello1` contains:

```
{"a" : "10", "b" : "20", "c" : "30"}
```

and you want to get that into a variable called `_value_`. If that is the case, you just do:

```
_value_=$(< hello1)
```

Then you can do:

```
echo "$_value_"
{"a" : "10", "b" : "20", "c" : "30"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a portable POSIX solution (no bashisms):

Contents of hello1 file:

```
{"a" : "10", "b" : "20", "c" : "30"}
```

POSIX shell code:

```
_value_="$(cat "hello1")"
echo "$_value_"
```

Output:

```
{"a" : "10", "b" : "20", "c" : "30"}
```

I'm not sure why you want to use `eval`.  That command is very dangerous, especially if you're not completely sure of the contents of the file you're reading.  Consider using [GNU envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) if you merely need variables interpreted (this seems unlikely given your JSON input):

```
_value_="$(envsubst < "hello1")"
echo "$_value_"
```