# Text in file manipulation

Tags: string, bash

I have a text file with text like this:

```
{"id":2705,"status":"Analyze","severity":"Critical",Blah Blah ... "file":"/home/foo.c","message":"Message is...","url":"http://aaa..."}
{"id":2706,"status":"Fix","severity":"Low",Blah Blah ... "file":"/home/foo1.h","message":"Message2 is...","url":"http://bbb..."}
```

I would like to have bash script, that reads file, and for each line use all pairs of data as variables (for example id=2705, status="Analyze"...) and echo them.

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem? Posting it and letting us know what failed will attract more answers.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Looking for a method to split into pairs. Not sure how to do it.
Want to have:
echo "id=2705"
echo "status=Analyze"...

Comment: You may find some inspiration here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511851/parsing-json-data-columnwise-in-shell

Comment: Always same pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk  'BEGIN{RS=",";FS=":";OFS="="}{$1=$1;gsub("}|{|\"","")}1' infile
id=2705
status=Analyze
severity=Critical
Blah Blah ... file=/home/foo.c
message=Message is...
url=http=//aaa...
id=2706
status=Fix
severity=Low
Blah Blah ... file=/home/foo1.h
message=Message2 is...
url=http=//bbb...
```

Comment: +1 for nice solution! The thing that keeps nagging me is any `json` aware tool would be even more ideal, as this does not guarantee when the formatting of the file is changed to a linear style.

Comment: I agree, Ideally json aware tool should be used.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks