# Get key-value pairs from JSON on OpenWRT (bash)

Tags: json, bash, openwrt

I'm working on an OpenWRT project where I need to get data from a server.
The data is in JSON format and looks something like this:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
```

I want to parse it to 2 arrays in bash, like this:

```
keys[0]=key1
keys[1]=key2
keys[2]=key3

values[0]=value1
values[1]=value2
values[2]=value3
```

I tired jshn.sh, but it only can extract values for known keys.

Comment: Check out these solutions- sed/awk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk or perl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858671/unix-command-line-json-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep` and `tr`:

```
declare -a keys=($(grep -Eo '"\w+":' json | tr -d \":))
declare -a values=($(grep -Eo ':"\w+"' json | tr -d \":))
```

Output:

```
$ for i in 0 1 2; do echo "${keys[$i]} - ${values[$i]}"; done
key1 - value1
key2 - value2
key3 - value3
```

In this case, I have assumed your JSON data is stored in a file named 'json' - this could be replaced with the output of a command like so:

```
declare -a keys=($(grep -Eo '"\w+":' <(curl www.example.com/json?q=test) | tr -d \":))
```

Comment: I like this solution because of the one-liner keys and values extraction. I changed the "\w+" part in the regexp to "([^"]*)" because i have some special characters in the values. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kyokai this solution is a little bit too low level. Since jshn is already installed in OpenWRT by default, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955082/jshn-how-to-parse-json-package is perhaps the best option. It will correctly parse JSON objects and nesting

Answer (score 3):

I would advise to use `jq` for solving your problem, but this package might be too heavy for the device you're running openwrt.

The main JSON parser on openwrt is provided by the `libubox` library. You can use this one to solve your problem.

```
. /usr/share/libubox/jshn.sh 
json_init
json_load '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}'
json_get_keys keys
for k in $keys; do 
   json_get_var v "$k"
   echo "$k : $v"
done
```

Comment: more details about the jshn in Wiki https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/jshn

Answer (score 0):

There are more suitable tools to read json files but you can try below:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    declare -A arr
    string='{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}'

    while read key value; do
        [[ -n "$key" ]] && arr["$key"]="$value"
    done < <(sed 's/[\"{}]//g' <<< "$string" | awk -F: 'BEGIN{RS=","} {print $1" "$2}')

    for i in ${!arr[@]}; do
        echo "$i -> ${arr[$i]}"
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/).

```
json='{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}'

keys=`echo $json | jq 'keys'`
values=`echo $json | jq '. | [.[]]'`
```

If you `echo "keys: $keys"; echo "values: $values"` this returns:

```
keys: [
  "key1",
  "key2",
  "key3"
]
values: [
  "value3",
  "value2",
  "value1"
]
```

I've noticed that in most of the Linux distro's I have used `jq` is included in the package manager. You can install it by performing `sudo apt-get install jq` or `sudo yum install jq`, depending on which package manager you use.

Comment: As far as a I know, there is no jq available for OpenWRT.