# How parse json file in openwrt 15.05

Tags: json, openwrt

I have valid json file. And don't know how parse and use it. 
I had tried this library  . /usr/share/libubox/jshn.sh from [jshn - how to parse json package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955082/jshn-how-to-parse-json-package), but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `jq` command line utility that's built to parse JSON from the command line. See [jq official website](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). You can build it from source for your distro.