# Struggling with awk

Tags: string, shell, curl, awk

I have a curl command which returns me this kind of json formated text

```
[{"id": "nUsrLast//device control", "name": "nUsrLast", "access": "readonly", "value": "0", "visibility": "visible", "type": "integer"}]
```

I would like to get the value of the field value.

Can someone give me a simple awk or grep command to do so ?

Comment: The value of the field value???

Comment: Perl is easier: `echo <your_json> | perl -e '<STDIN> =~ /\"value\"\s*:\s*\"(([^"]|\\")*)\"/; print $1;'` <-- Tested that, it works. The value in quotes can contain any character other than `"`, but it can also contain backslash-escaped `"` (i.e. `\"`).

Comment: @ParthianShot Looks like the awk below is easiest.

Comment: @ooga True. But it's also wrong, as I pointed out in the comments below it.

Comment: You might also want to check out the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858671/unix-command-line-json-parser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -v RS="," -F\" '/value/ {print $4}' file
0
```

How does it work?
Setting `RS` to `,` it breaks line to some like this:

```
awk -v RS="," '{$1=$1}1' file
[{"id": "nUsrLast//device control"
"name": "nUsrLast"
"access": "readonly"
"value": "0"
"visibility": "visible"
"type": "integer"}]
```

Then `/value/ {print $4}` prints field `4` separated by `"`

Comment: Does this handle backslash-escaped double quotes in the string? And commas in the strings?

Comment: @ParthianShot Obviously not, but the data does not seem to require it.

Comment: Well, assumedly he doesn't want a solution that only works on the specific string given. He's making a curl request and getting arbitrary JSON data. If one of the fields is `"name":"Bob, the builder",` everything breaks. And he didn't specify the value of `value` could only be numeric.

Comment: @ParthianShot It will not brake, since it only cares about the section with `value` in it.  Does not matter how many `,` there are.  But if you have `va,lue`, you get problem, but when do you see some like that?

Comment: @Jotne So you're saying this will work if you have something like `"value": "John \"the one, the only\" Smith"`?

Comment: @ParthianShot No, but I do assume that value always comes after an handle.  If the handle has `,` in, you need to take in care that it does.  A normal handle is  `value=0`, `value:0` etc

Comment: @Jotne That's fair. I only wanted to bring it up so that someone reading the answer is aware of its limitations. If they're only dealing with a numeric field, your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You could use grep with `oP` parameters,

```
$ echo '[{"id": "nUsrLast//device control", "name": "nUsrLast", "access": "readonly", "value": "0", "visibility": "visible", "type": "integer"}]' | grep -oP '(?<=\"value\": \")[^"]*'
0
```

From `grep --help`,

- `-P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression`
- `-o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN`

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `(?<=\"value\": \")` Lookbehind is used to set or place the matching marker. In our case, regex engine places the matching marker just after to the string `"value": "`.
- `[^"]*` Now it matches any character except `"` zero or more times. When a `"` is detected then the regex engine would stop it's matching operation.

Comment: You need to explain the regex, too. :-)

Comment: I partially fixed it, but there's a fundamental flaw with this regex, which is that, if the JSON is malformed / the curl request fails partway through, and you get something like `{"value": "this is half a st`, it will silently match `this is half a st`. It doesn't check that the value is terminated with a `"` symbol, which is an error condition.

Comment: @ParthianShot for your malformed file `grep -oP '(?<=\"value\": \")[^",]*'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Then you always get the trailing `"` and must remove it.

Comment: How i get the trailing `"` in my output? Could you post an example.

Answer (score 0):

This solution isn't grep or awk but chances are pretty good your system has perl on it, and this is the best solution thus far:

```
echo <your_json> | perl -e '<STDIN> =~ /\"value\"\s*:\s*\"(([^"]|\\")*)\"/; print $1;'
```

It handles the possibility of a failed request by ensuring there is a trailing `"` character. It also handles backslash-escaped `"` symbols in the string and whitespace between "value" and the colon character.

It does *not* handle JSON broken across multiple lines, but then none of the other solutions do, either.

`\"value\"\s*:\s*\"` Ensures that we're dealing with the correct field, then

`(([^"]|\\")*)` Captures the associated valid JSON string

\" Makes sure the string is properly terminated

Frankly, you're better off using a [real JSON parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858671/unix-command-line-json-parser), though.