# FIltering by value in jq while building regex patterns

Tags: regex, json, jq

While trying to create a version of input to feed into my actual code, I need to create a file that enable to get "contains" a string with case sensitive version of string, in a value for a key. 
i.e **building a regex to implement "contains"** "camfrog or tubemate, or soundclould" .

Sample JSON input :

```
{"appid":"537c6d4a9c4846b8bc44ebdf78ab8e2d","app_name":"TubeMate
YouTube Downloader","publisher_id":"1690d6387fcc441091a2f2d73f89709d"}
{"appid":"f8022204aaa7478a88fca1a417ddb125","app_name":"Camfrog
Android Smartphone","publisher_id":"085d0268a9674ce885a2f185ec895246"}
{"appid":"agltb3B1Yi1pbmNyDAsSA0FwcBih9tMUDA","app_name":"TuneIn Radio
- iPad","publisher_id":"agltb3B1Yi1pbmNyEAsSB0FjY291bnQYsv-PFAw"} {"appid":"537c6d4a9c4846b8bc44ebdf78ab8e2d","app_name":"TubeMate
YouTube Downloader","publisher_id":"1690d6387fcc441091a2f2d73f89709d"}
{"appid":"f8022204aaa7478a88fca1a417ddb125","app_name":"Camfrog
Android Smartphone","publisher_id":"085d0268a9674ce885a2f185ec895246"}
 {"appid":"92255b8b662148e59973b8eca128adde","app_name":"SubwaySimulator3D","publisher_id":"0d78f4d244ec4309b4aa06cdfb871341"}
{"appid":"agltb3B1Yi1pbmNyDAsSA0FwcBjq_6EUDA","app_name":"TuneIn
Radio","publisher_id":"agltb3B1Yi1pbmNyEAsSB0FjY291bnQYsv-PFAw"}
{"appid":"f7cc119ca9e1426c8d162d2d37c8558f","app_name":"Android Skout
New","publisher_id":"agltb3B1Yi1pbmNyEAsSB0FjY291bnQY7cCnEgw"}
{"appid":"agltb3B1Yi1pbmNyDAsSA0FwcBim6MAVDA","app_name":"Draw
Something
Android","publisher_id":"agltb3B1Yi1pbmNyEAsSB0FjY291bnQYgYC-FQw"}
```

From this Json input I need to filter apps that have names "like" Camfrog (It can be CAMFROG, camfrog .. etc, so the regex has to be case insensitive.along with this, I need to output a series of app_names like, say "Camfrog", "Tubemate", "soundcloud" etc. 
I looked up the jq manual here, http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/, but couldn't build the expression.

Here's what I tried -:

```
 </home/ekta/Prototype1/sample.dat jq -c '{app_name:.app_name} |
 match(["Camfrog", "ig"])'  
 map(select(.app.name like "%Camfrog%" ))
```

But I get match is not defined & a compile error thereof. How can I do this within Jq.

fallback -:
I could load this as a dataframe in pandas, and do the regex there,but since my file has a tons of things I dont really need, I would like to filter quickly in Jq.

sample output after filtering for the apps ( I need all the key,values as in orignal output-:

```
{"appid":"537c6d4a9c4846b8bc44ebdf78ab8e2d","app_name":"TubeMate
YouTube Downloader","publisher_id":"1690d6387fcc441091a2f2d73f89709d"}
{"appid":"f8022204aaa7478a88fca1a417ddb125","app_name":"Camfrog
Android Smartphone","publisher_id":"085d0268a9674ce885a2f185ec895246"}
{"appid":"537c6d4a9c4846b8bc44ebdf78ab8e2d","app_name":"TubeMate
YouTube Downloader","publisher_id":"1690d6387fcc441091a2f2d73f89709d"}
{"appid":"f8022204aaa7478a88fca1a417ddb125","app_name":"Camfrog
Android Smartphone","publisher_id":"085d0268a9674ce885a2f185ec895246"}
```

**PPS :** Will appreciate if you could "Teach me to fish", instead of just building the regex that should be matched.

**Follow up Question-:**

Also, when I try to test the sample examples, in the jq manual , like -:

> echo [{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}, {"foo": 1, "bar": 3}, {"foo": 4, "bar":
>   5}] | jq 'unique(.foo)

I get , error: too many arguments to unique (expected 0 but got 1) unique(.foo)1 compile error

While the jq manual reads, a sample example as below -:

> ```
> jq 'unique(.foo)'
> Input [{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}, {"foo": 1, "bar": 3}, {"foo": 4, "bar": 5}]
> Output    [{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}, {"foo": 4, "bar": 5}]
> ```

**How else should I try out the input here ?**

The way I am building my dictionary really is , `</home/ekta/SamplePrototype.dat jq -c '{appid:.app.id,,app_name:.app.name,publisher_id:.app.publisher_id}'` , but I would like to test things as in jq manual. Could you give me pointers about what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Regular expression matching in jq hasn't made it to the release version yet. The next release should have it. If you build from source, it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what worked for my, by our old good friend, Grep(and egrep)

```
$<sample.dat  jq -c '{appid:.appid,app_name:.app_name}'  | egrep -i "camfrog|draw something"
{"appid":"f8022204aaa7478a88fca1a417ddb125","app_name":"Camfrog Android Smartphone"}
{"appid":"f8022204aaa7478a88fca1a417ddb125","app_name":"Camfrog Android Smartphone"}
{"appid":"agltb3B1Yi1pbmNyDAsSA0FwcBim6MAVDA","app_name":"Draw Something Android"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a combination of `select` `ascii_downcase` and `test`, like so:

```bash
$ echo '[{"thing": "foo"}, {"thing":"Foo"}, {"thing":"fOo"}, {"thing":"Bar"}]' \
    | jq '.[] | select(.thing | ascii_downcase | test("foo"))'

    {
      "thing": "foo"
    }
    {
       "thing": "Foo"
    }
    {
      "thing": "fOo" 
    }
```

`select` takes a list and returns only certain elements from it

`ascii_downcase` converts everything to lowercase

`test` uses a regular expression to see if `select` should include the item or not