# Replace sed variable value from a json file

Tags: linux, sed

I have a sed command that I use to insert a line into a shell script. The name of the script into which I insert varies in every env I'm trying to do this in. This works if I provide the values but when I need to repeat this across a large number of environments I need it to fetch these values from a json file. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Syntax -> `sed -i '1 a if ! [ipaddress = <value> && OSTYPE = linux]; then exit(1); endif' qa-<envname>-vm1.sh`

```
sed -i '1 a if ! [ipaddress = 0.0.0.0 && OSTYPE = linux]; then exit(1); endif' qa-QAF-vm1.sh
```

inserts

`if ! [ipaddress = 0.0.0.0 && OSTYPE = linux]; then exit(1); endif` after the first line in the file `qa-QAF-vm1.sh`.

Any ideas how I can fetch the `ipaddress value` and `envname` from a json file which lists these values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix command-line JSON parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858671/unix-command-line-json-parser)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/) to query elements from a JSON data structure.

```
JSON='{"ipaddress": "10.10.10.10", "ostype": "linux"}'

ipaddress=$(jq -r .ipaddress <<<"$JSON")
ostype=$(jq -r .ostype <<<"$JSON")

echo $ipaddress
echo $ostype
```

Comment: Thanks @ceving - will give it a try.

Comment: I solved this issue myself by generating the aforementioned shell script using embedded Ruby without any seperate json parser