# JSON to JSON transformation (preferably inside Apache Camel)

Tags: json, apache-camel, transformation

I have somewhat unique requirement, which I could not find an answer to so far. I need a JSON to JSON transformation. Preferably, if I could plug it into Apache Camel, that would be wonderful.

As a side note, I would also welcome any suggestion to optimally store the JSON to JSON mapping. Is there any XSLT-based way of achieving this?

Thanks!
Mario

Comment: Is the JSON to JSON transformation a completely uncommmon requirement? Is this because normally JSON -> POJO -> JSON the way to do it?

Comment: This question has already been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618038/xslt-equivalent-for-json

Answer (score 2):

ZORBA with jsonIQ : http://www.jsoniq.org/
it's a native library, but with high performance. You have examples in the web page.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but to refresh the answers, starting from Camel **2.16** there is a new [component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/jolt-component.html) for [JOLT](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) integration. It is very powerful !

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple design here:  https://rawgithub.com/chunqishi/edu.brandeis.cs.json2json/master/docs/design-2014-04-09.html

May be you can improve it by source code,  https://github.com/chunqishi/edu.brandeis.cs.json2json.