# Looking for a DSL to convert JSON to CSV

Tags: python, transform, dsl

I need to convert hierarchical data (AVRO data, which boils down to JSON) into tabular data (csv). Since AVRO have strict schema, I know essentially what form the JSON will take, but I have to do this for many different schema, so I'm looking for a consistent, declarative way to express the transformations I need to make. For example, if my incoming data looks like this…

```
{
    "customers": [
        {
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "city": "Los Angeles", 
                    "country": "USA", 
                    "county": null, 
                    "postalCode": "90064", 
                    "stateOrProvince": "California", 
                    "street1": "11832 W. Pico Blvd.", 
                    "street2": "", 
                    "street3": "", 
                    "street4": "", 
                    "tags": [
                        "BILLING"
                    ]
                }
            ], 
            "company": "", 
            "dateCreated": "2009-04-24T11:42:31+00:00", 
            "dateOfBirth": null, 
            "doNotCall": null, 
            "email": {
                "emailAddress": "general@magentocommerce.com"
            }, 
            "emailOptOut": null, 
            "fullName": {
                "firstName": "Test", 
                "lastName": "General", 
                "middleName": "", 
                "prefix": "", 
                "suffix": ""
            }, 
            "gender": null, 
            "id": {
                "Id": "2", 
                "namespace": "1000020016"
            }, 
            "lastModified": "2009-05-08T23:33:06+00:00", 
            "primaryPhone": {
                "number": "866.4.VARIEN", 
                "type": "UNKNOWN"
            }, 
            "sourceIds": null
        }
    ], 
    "totalItemsFound": 3
}
```

…I might need to output one row for each customer, like this:

```
MERCHANT ID|NUM CUSTOMERS|ID|FIRST NAME|LAST NAME|EMAIL|PHONE|STREET|CITY|STATE|ZIP|COUNTRY|EMAIL PREFERENCE
some.merch|3|1000020016-2|Test|General|general@magentocommerce.com|866.4.VARIEN|11832 W. Pico Blvd.|Los Angeles|California|90064|USA|N
```

I need to be able to express the following things:

1. Get all the values from a given key as an array: *All the dates-of-birth*
2. Repeat one value over every row: *totalItemsFound, repeated in every row*
3. Repeat a static value in every row that comes from static data I already know *the merchant channel never changes*
4. And the tricky one: Arbitrarily manipulate the incoming data to produce the desired output:

   - *Convert the customer's id into namespace-id*
   - *Invert and change a null/boolean value into y/n, as in emailOptOut to EMAIL PREFERENCE*
   - *(re-)format a date or currency*
   - etc

I started out with [jsonpath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), but that only solves #1 above. I've been slowly adding a language around jsonpath to serve 2 and 3, but I really don't have a good answer for 4 (besides eval., and I'd really hate to do that). I looked at [JSON/T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618038), but couldn't find a python library for it. I even seriously considered writing a middleware to convert the JSON into XML so that I could use XSLT, but I'm hoping someone here at S/O has a better solution before I get that desperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not attempt a functional decomposition not unlike what follows:

```
w = csv.writer(...)
for r in records: 
    l = {}
    for field in fields:
        f_ = rename(field)
        v_ = transform(field, r.get(field, default(field)))
        l[f_] = v_
    w.write(l)
```

where `rename` maps the old field names to the new ones, and `transform` converts the field's value depending on the transform set for the field, and `default` returns the value to be assigned to this field.

So you would only need to define the list of fields, and the functions: `rename`, `transform`, and `default`.

For the example you've given:

```
def rename(field):
    t = {'emailOptOut':'EMAIL PREFERENCE'}
    return t.get(field, field)

def transform(field, data):
    t = {'emailOptOut': bool}
    return t.get(field, lambda a: a)(data)

def default(field)
    t = {'MERCHANT ID':11039215}
    return t.get(field, None)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to think about this answer. Unfortunately for my usual S/O workflow, this question isn't one I can just look at an answer and decide it's right. :)