# jsonpatch all elements in array

Tags: javascript, json

The below post led me to evaluate using jsonpatch for json to json transformation:

[JSON to JSON transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068267/json-to-json-transformer)

The project can be found here:

https://github.com/bruth/jsonpatch-js

I am currently trying to change the name of all elements in an array and am not seeing how this is possible. My current attempt is:

```
var transformations = [{ op: 'move', from:'/hits/1/_id', path: '/hits/1/pizza'}];
```

This swaps out the first element but how do I do a "*" card type operation? Something like:

```
var transformations = [{ op: 'move', from:'/hits/*/_id', path: '/hits/*/pizza'}];
```

I could see possibly calling the transformation N times for each element but that seems like a hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up using an approach where I wrapped the call to apply in a loop:

```
 for(i=0;i<json.hits.length;i++) {
    var transformations = [{ op: 'move', from:'/hits/'+i+'/_id', path:'/hits/'+i+'/pizza'}];
    var result = jsonpatch.apply(json,transformations);             
 }
```

Maybe jsonpatch could use a wildcard feature?