# JSON To JSON Transformation | Template Engine for Java

Tags: java, json, xslt, transform

I have a requirement to transform an incoming JSON to an output JSON. For this I am looking for a solution that can work based on templates. What I have in my mind is a solution on lines of XSLT transformation that allows converting an XML to a desired output format (XML, HTML, Text) defined by the style sheet.

One option(or rather a workaround) to use XSLT is to convert JSON to XML that is:

```
input JSON -> XML -> transform -> output JSON
```

This approach would have a performance overhead of converting JSON to XML and this would become prominent as the size of incoming object increases.

I found a Node/client layer solution that transforms JSON based on the rules specified in a template. More details about can be found [here][1]. However, I was not able to find any solution that works for a java based application.

Any thoughts/help in terms of solution/frameworks to resolve this would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do a conversion to XML??

Comment: @GaneshThiagarajan, I have clearly mentioned that conversion to XML is more of a workaround rather than an optimal solution. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068267/json-to-json-transformer

Comment: Thanks @Damian for your inputs.

Answer (score 4):

You could try [JOLT](http://bazaarvoice.github.io/jolt/), advertised as a  JSON to JSON transformation library written in Java.

Or you can search this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618038/xslt-equivalent-for-json) for other libraries and tools which can transform JSON.

The new [XSLT 3.0 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json) also includes support for JSON as input and output format. Saxon has already started an implementation and seems to [support](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/fn/json-to-xml.html) for the JSON part.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [JSLT](https://github.com/schibsted/jslt), which is a transform language where you write the fixed part of the output in JSON syntax, then insert expressions to compute the values you want to insert in the template. It's quite similar to how XSLT and XPath work together.

It's implemented in Java on top of Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

For simple transformations you can use [jmom](https://github.com/antonsjava/jmom) library.

For a complex transformation you can use template framework like freemarker. 
And convert json data to Map/List form using [json](https://github.com/antonsjava/json) library so it can be used by template framework.