# Using JSONata in Java throws exception

Tags: java, json, exception, jsonata

I am trying to use `JSONata` in `java`.

```
JSONata version - 1.4.0
Java Version - 1.8
```

Steps:
Included `Jsonata.js` in the class path.

Invocation:

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
FileReader jsonata = new FileReader("jsonata.js");
// load the JSONata processor
engine.eval(jsonata);
```

Reference link:
[How can I use JSONata in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416032/how-can-i-use-jsonata-in-java/48312615)

When I try to use this i get the below exception:

> Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ParserException:
>   :1445:12  Expected ( but found *function* evaluate(expr, input,
>   environment) {
>
> at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.error(AbstractParser.java:294)
>   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.error(AbstractParser.java:279)
>   at 
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.expectDontAdvance(AbstractParser.java:350)
>   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.expect(AbstractParser.java:337)
>   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.functionExpression(Parser.java:2654)
>   at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.statement(Parser.java:875) at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.sourceElements(Parser.java:773) at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.functionBody(Parser.java:2901) at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.functionExpression(Parser.java:2663)
>   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.memberExpression(Parser.java:2506)
>   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.leftHandSideExpression(Parser.java:2372)
>   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.unaryExpression(Parser.java:3147)
>   at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.expression(Parser.java:3282) at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.primaryExpression(Parser.java:1992)
>   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.memberExpression(Parser.java:2511)
>   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.leftHandSideExpression(Parser.java:2372)
>   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.unaryExpression(Parser.java:3147)
>   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.assignmentExpression(Parser.java:3353)
>   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.variableStatement(Parser.java:1088)
>   at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.statement(Parser.java:884) at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.sourceElements(Parser.java:773) at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.program(Parser.java:709) at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:283) at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:249) at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compile(Context.java:1284) at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:1251)
>   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:627)
>   at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:535)
>   ... 6 moree

Any help on how to use it will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v1.2, jsonata.js uses ES6 features, so you'll need to make sure the version of Nashorn you are using supports this.  Alternatively, you can use the jsonata-es5.js version that gets generated by Babel in the JSONata build.  You can get this either by cloning the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata) and running `npm t`, or by downloading it from [here](https://unpkg.com/jsonata@1.4.1/jsonata-es5.min.js).

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the function Evaluate with three parameters, You only given the expression . Based on the link you should also provide the ff

Code :

```
engine.put("input", new String(sample));
and 
engine.put("resultjson", resultjson);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Leroy.The actual problem was like Andrew mentioned, The version of Nashorn script engine I am using does not support the ES6  features.So using jsonata-es5.js solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that earlier versions of JSONata function with the nashorn engine in `java version "1.8.0_152"` using either the link to jsonata-es5.min.js provided by Andrew or `jsonata.git/tags/v1.1.1/jsonata.js` from the jsonata repostiory.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a Java port of the JSONata JavaScript code. Please see this question's answers for details: [How can I use JSONata in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416032/how-can-i-use-jsonata-in-java/55034068#55034068)