# JSON-to-JSON transformation: possible approaches

Tags: java, json, ecmascript-6, xml-to-json

Sometimes there’s a need to perform a same-format transformation from one structure into another.
Now before you start with the implementation, you first need the theoretical basis. therefore my question to you is what possible approaches for the transformation are possible for JSON to JSON?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068267/json-to-json-transformer

Comment: there are many implementations but what I am looking for is the basis for it. is this about a regüal expressions manipulation etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a JSON string: convert into a HashMap, do what you have to do then convert back to JSON.  You can use a library such as JSON.simple
https://mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/