# JSON JQ Find Replace Value

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to update "image_id" value in a json structure. Using the below command, how do I change `ami-d8cf5cab` to `ami-a4df7gah` So far, I have tried this

```
cat cog.test.tfstate | jq -r '.modules[].resources[] | select(.type == "aws_launch_configuration") | select(.primary.attributes.name_prefix == "pmsadmin-lc-")'
```

The JSON data is

```
{
  "type": "aws_launch_configuration",
  "primary": {
    "id": "pmsadmin-lc-v47thk6rcrdgza6dujfzjatmju",
    "attributes": {
      "associate_public_ip_address": "false",
      "ebs_block_device.#": "0",
      "ebs_optimized": "false",
      "enable_monitoring": "true",
      "ephemeral_block_device.#": "0",
      "iam_instance_profile": "cog-test-pmsadmin",
      "id": "pmsadmin-lc-v47thk6rcrdgza6dujfzjatmju",
      "image_id": "ami-d8cf5cab",
      "instance_type": "t2.small",
      "key_name": "cog-test-internal",
      "name": "pmsadmin-lc-v47thk6rcrdgza6dujfzjatmju",
      "name_prefix": "pmsadmin-lc-",
      "root_block_device.#": "0",
      "security_groups.#": "4",
      "security_groups.1893851868": "sg-7ee7bf1a",
      "security_groups.2774384192": "sg-e2e7bf86",
      "security_groups.2825850029": "sg-86e6bee2",
      "security_groups.3095009517": "sg-f4e7bf90",
      "spot_price": "",
      "user_data": "ed03ac6642af8c97562b065c0b37f211b58ad0a2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A long list of jq alternatives can also be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011455/2440

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `|=` operator to assign to a property:

```
jq -r '.modules[].resources[] | select(.type == "aws_launch_configuration") | select(.primary.attributes.name_prefix == "pmsadmin-lc-")| .primary.attributes.image_id |= "ami-a4df7gah"
```

Comment: Is there a way to edit in place i.e. update the value straight in the json file?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @hek2mgl - In case you haven't noticed, the first Q in the General Questions section of the jq FAQ (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#general-questions) is now about "in-place" editing.

Comment: You can redirect output with a >

Comment: As in
`cat cog.test.tfstate | jq '.modules[].foo=0' > bar.json`

Comment: When using the redirect on the same file, it will result in an empty file. You can prevent that by using the `sponge` command instead (https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge)