# Newtonsoft JSON dynamic custom property names

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I got a data model like that:

```
public struct Person
{
    public string Name;
    public Address[] Addresses;
}

public struct Address
{
    public string HouseNumber;
    public string StreetName;
}
```

I want to use Newtonsoft JSON (or an alternative) to serialize and deserialize an array of persons to two different data sources/web APIs, both names the properties differently.

For example, source 1 would return something like:

```
[{"name":"John", "addresses":[{"house":12, "name","Floura St"}]}]
```

While source 2 is like:

```
[{"person-name":"John", "addresses":[{"houseNumber":12, "street-name","Floura St"}]}]
```

Actual data can have more or less fields from different sources.

My idea was to have two different `JsonSerializerSettings` with different `ContractResolver` or different `JsonConverter[]` for the two different sources.

1. I tried overriding `ResolvePropertyName` of `DefaultContractResolver` but didn't work because there is no way to know which type it is resolving property names for. I need that because some properties has the same name between different types.
2. I've also tried overriding `CreateProperties` in `DefaultContractResolver` but didn't figure out how to change the mapping for the property name.
3. Finally I tried writing something like this:

   ```
   private class DynamicConverter<T> : JsonConverter
   {
       public DynamicConverter(Dictionary<string, string> propertiesMap)
       {
       }

       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return objectType == typeof(T);
       }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
           JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
       }
   }
   ```

But I am not sure if that is the correct way to go, specially that I will need to write all the read and write code from scratch as I guess. Is there a better way to just override the behaviour I am interested in changing without reinventing the wheel? Also I am not sure what I will do with creating a new instance of `Person` and `Address` because they are structures and not classes.

> NOTE: As you may have already guessed, I don't have much access to
>   change the model structs to make them classes or to tag them with
>   Newtonsoft JSON attributes. In fact my team prefer to leave them
>   untouched and not referencing JSON libraries because the model structs
>   live in a common library that is used for a lot of other stuff not
>   related to JSON serialization.
>
> Also note that this is a simple example to demonstrate my problem, the
>   actual data structure is way more complicated, for example there are
>   tens of structs and nested arrays of more than two levels.

Comment: Seemingly you have multiple source Json formats which you would like to map to a single (canonical) entity model. Xslt was ideal for this in xml - have a [look for equivalent Json tech](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1618038/314291)

Comment: @BrianRogers, I think that answers my question, thanks Brian although I hoped for a clean way to have an JSON mapper per struct type rather than a big map of maps, but this is still a good solution, thanks

Comment: @StuartLC, JSONT sounds promising, but couldn't find a C# library as famous as newtonsoft to use, newtonsoft guys don't want to implement it apparently as appears on their issue tracking.