# JSON Schema Validation for PL/SQL or SQL, similar to XSLT for XML Schema Validation

Tags: json, plsql, oracle12c

I am looking for the schema validation for JSON structure received during the API Invocation from ORDS. Lets say I have 10 different json tags constructing the JSON and I want to validate this JSON against pre-defined validation to check if any required parameters are missing or to validate the datatype.

I am looking for the functionality similar to XLST which is used for XML schema validation.

Please note this schema validation is required for the JSON using PL/SQL and ORDS(Oracle Rest Database Services).

Technical Components: SQL, PL/SQL, ORDS. We want something which is compatible with the mentioned components.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT equivalent for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618038/xslt-equivalent-for-json)

Comment: Hello Sushil. Firstly, I think your question has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618038/xslt-equivalent-for-json
And secondly, why would you tag this question with plsql, oracle12c and plsqldeveloper?

Comment: Hello Lee, This is tagged in pl/sql and oracle because I am looking to code using pl/sql. The objective is to have a JSON schema validation for the JSON generated using SQL and PL/SQL.