# Data mapping using XML or JSON using JSON or XML definition

Tags: java, json, xml, map-force

I have a product, where I have a producer and a consumer. Currently the producer produces one json format and the consumer consumes a different json format. Hence after producing the json, I convert the json as like consumer format so consumer can consume without any issue.

But now the requirement is different where any number of consumer can come to consume the json and different consumers can consume different format of JSON. In this case, any new consumer comes, I get an error as the new consumer cannot support the existing json.

One way is to support it through Apigee or Mulesoft where it supports data mapping for different XML or JSON format but ApiGee or Mulesoft are very costly to me.

I am using Java stack now. Is there any way to support data mapping over JSON or XML where I just need to define the JSON or XML definition how it should be for the new consumer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618038/xslt-equivalent-for-json seems to be very similar to your question. There might be newer solutions but this probably helps?

If you have XML input and XML output, of course you could just use XSLT.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check the same. Just a ask, if I can get any idea which particular library/libraries from the above URL, I can use as trusted for JSON to JSON mapping in my java application.

Comment: Just eager to know whether OpenAPI specification provides such transformation without changing low level coding?

Comment: Underscore-java library can convert xml to json or vice versa. U.xmlToJson(xml) / U.jsonToXml(json) methods will help.