# XML to JSON and JSON to XML back in C#?

Tags: c#, json, xml

How can I convert XML to JSON and JSON to XML back in my C# application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/json-net-convert-json-string-to-xml-or-xml-to-json-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work: http://www.phdcc.com/xml2json.htm

Comment: Yes its working. But i'm looking for a well tested dll. because some time this may have some limitation to convert to some data types.