# convert json to xml with json.net

Tags: .net, xml, json.net

I'm tring to find an example of using json.net to convert a json response to xml. I'm not sure if I should be using LINQ to JSON or XmlNodeConverter or what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/json-net-convert-json-string-to-xml-or-xml-to-json-string

Answer (score 2):

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

The section 'Converting between JSON and XML' should really help. It has some simple examples.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used json.net but if you have a clr collection you you could use linq to produce the xml for you.

For example:

```
var xml = 
    new XElement("people",
    from x in personCollection
    orderby x.LastName
    select new XElement("person",
        new XAttribute("personId", x.PersonId),
        new XElement("firstName", x.FirstName),
        new XElement("lastName", x.LastName)))
    );
```

And an exmple output would be something like:

```
<people>
    <person ID="1">
        <firstName>first-name-1</firstName>
        <lastName>last-name-1</lastName>
    </person>
    <person ID="2">
        <firstName>first-name-2</firstName>
        <lastName>last-name-2</lastName>
    </person>
    <person ID="1">
        <firstName>first-name-3</name>
        <lastName>last-name-3</lastName>
    </person>
</people>
```