# How to convert XML to JSON using C#/LINQ?

Tags: c#, json, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following XML file that I need to convert to JSON in the server. Initially I thought I would convert it to a Dictionary and then use the JavaScriptSerializer to turn it into JSON but since each column could have a different value type, I don't think it would work. Has anyone done something similar before in C#/LINQ?

I need to preserve the Value Types(Boolean, String, Integer) of each column.

I would appreciate any advice on this as Im just starting to work with XML. Thanks.

```
<Columns>
 <Column Name="key1" DataType="Boolean">True</Column>
 <Column Name="key2" DataType="String">Hello World</Column>
 <Column Name="key3" DataType="Integer">999</Column>
</Columns>
```

Comment: Do you need to keep the value of `DataType`? If not it could be transformed into a simple associative array.

Comment: Yes I need to keep the Data Type, Other wise I would have just converted it to a dictionary!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON to XML or XML to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var xml = 
        @"<Columns>
          <Column Name=""key1"" DataType=""Boolean"">True</Column>
          <Column Name=""key2"" DataType=""String"">Hello World</Column>
          <Column Name=""key3"" DataType=""Integer"">999</Column>
        </Columns>";
        var dic = XDocument
            .Parse(xml)
            .Descendants("Column")
            .ToDictionary(
                c => c.Attribute("Name").Value, 
                c => c.Value
            );
        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dic);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

produces:

```
{"key1":"True","key2":"Hello World","key3":"999"}
```

Obviously this treats all the values as strings. If you want to keep the underlying type semantics you could do the following:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var xml = 
        @"<Columns>
          <Column Name=""key1"" DataType=""System.Boolean"">True</Column>
          <Column Name=""key2"" DataType=""System.String"">Hello World</Column>
          <Column Name=""key3"" DataType=""System.Int32"">999</Column>
        </Columns>";
        var dic = XDocument
            .Parse(xml)
            .Descendants("Column")
            .ToDictionary(
                c => c.Attribute("Name").Value, 
                c => Convert.ChangeType(
                    c.Value,
                    typeof(string).Assembly.GetType(c.Attribute("DataType").Value, true)
                )
            );
        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dic);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

produces:

```
{"key1":true,"key2":"Hello World","key3":999}
```

And if you cannot modify the underlying XML structure you will need a custom function that will convert between your custom types and the underlying .NET type:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var xml = 
        @"<Columns>
          <Column Name=""key1"" DataType=""Boolean"">True</Column>
          <Column Name=""key2"" DataType=""String"">Hello World</Column>
          <Column Name=""key3"" DataType=""Integer"">999</Column>
        </Columns>";
        var dic = XDocument
            .Parse(xml)
            .Descendants("Column")
            .ToDictionary(
                c => c.Attribute("Name").Value, 
                c => Convert.ChangeType(
                    c.Value, 
                    GetType(c.Attribute("DataType").Value)
                )
            );
        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dic);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

    private static Type GetType(string type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Integer":
                return typeof(int);
            case "String":
                return typeof(string);
            case "Boolean":
                return typeof(bool);
            // TODO: add any other types that you want to support
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    string.Format("The type {0} is not supported", type)
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, will this preserve the value types of the columns?

Comment: Real NICE :D , Thank you for this!

Comment: Yes, the second and the third approach will preserve the value types.

Comment: For reference, you need to reference the "System.Web.Extensions.dll" for JavaScriptSerializer to resolve.

Answer (score 27):

Is it necessary to use LINQ? Otherwise you can try this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

Taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/json-net-convert-json-string-to-xml-or-xml-to-json-string).

Comment: No, but LINQ is much cooler and I'm trying to learn new stuff, btw Is this gonna keep the Data Type of the columns?

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but maybe I can test it later to tell you whether the data type is kept.

Answer (score 3):

For deep nesting of XML elements with more and unknown attributes you can use this recursion:

```
private static string XmlToJson(string xmlString)
{
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(GetXmlValues(XElement.Parse(xmlString)));
}

private static Dictionary<string, object> GetXmlValues(XElement xml)
{
    var attr = xml.Attributes().ToDictionary(d => d.Name.LocalName, d => (object)d.Value);
    if (xml.HasElements) attr.Add("_value", xml.Elements().Select(e => GetXmlValues(e)));
    else if (!xml.IsEmpty) attr.Add("_value", xml.Value);

    return new Dictionary<string, object> { { xml.Name.LocalName, attr } };
}
```

For your example the result will be:

```
{
    "Columns":{
        "_value":[
            {
                "Column":{
                    "Name":"key1",
                    "DataType":"Boolean",
                    "_value":"True"
                }
            },
            {
                "Column":{
                    "Name":"key2",
                    "DataType":"String",
                    "_value":"Hello World"
                }
            },
            {
                "Column":{
                    "Name":"key3",
                    "DataType":"Integer",
                    "_value":"999"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And for more complex XML case like [this](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=Q2303322&format=xml), you can check the JSON analogue [here](http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidate/cb0aef63).