# C# JavasScriptSerializer in Windows 8

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

In this thread: [How to convert XML to JSON using C#/LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037085/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-using-c-linq)
i found the code for Converting XML to Json. I tried to implement this to Windows 8 but i have a Problem that the:

```
 JavaScriptSerializer
```

doesn't exist in Windows 8. Does any one know the assembly for the JavaScriptSerializer?

```
 var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dic);
```

Comment: try `JSerialize` found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13705/JavaScript-Serializer)

Comment: try 'DataContractJsonSerializer' as it's part of the WinRT framework, or JSON.Net @ http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: @leon DataContractJsonSerializer was found under System.Runtime.Serialization.Json; But i can't find the method for serializing... can you answer the question and if it works i can give you the Reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Web.Scripting.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`

Requires `System.Web.Extensions.dll` as a reference.

Edit: If you're constrained to WinRT, check out http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: Indeed it isn't (really you should have specified WinRT in your original question :P) - I don't know if JSON.Net (http://json.codeplex.com/) works in WinRT but it's worth looking at.

Comment: i thought it's clear because of .net-4.5 sorry for that mistake i'll change it :)

Comment: .net 4.5 doesn't necessarily mean WinRT, you can build WPF/Winforms/ASP.Net that use .Net 4.5 and aren't constrained to WinRT.

Comment: this worked for implementing even if i have another Problem coming up with this solution...

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the

```
JSonSerialiserHelper
```

For example:

```
string objectText = GetJSONObj();
MyJsonObj myJsonObj = JSonSerialiserHelper.Deserialize<MyJsonObj>(objectText);
```