# Extracting from XML string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

How can I write a program that turns this XML string

```
<outer>
  <inner>
    <boom>
      <name>John</name>
      <address>New York City</address>
    </boom>

    <boom>
      <name>Daniel</name>
      <address>Los Angeles</address>
    </boom>

    <boom>
      <name>Joe</name>
      <address>Chicago</address>
    </boom>
  </inner>
</outer>
```

into this string

```
name: John
address: New York City

name: Daniel
address: Los Angeles

name: Joe
address: Chicago
```

Can LINQ make it easier?

Comment: You could use [LINQ2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) or [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) ....

Comment: Look at this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037085/convert-xml-to-json-using-c-linq

Comment: You should look into learning XPath: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164116.aspx

Comment: @Renan You most definitely should not.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I'm interested in the reason for that. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Renan XPath is an old, clunky technology that is stringly typed, and the error is way more specific.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Linq-to-XML:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("MyDocument.xml");  // Loads the XML document with to use with Linq-to-XML

var booms = from boomElement in document.Descendants("boom")  // Go through the collection of boom elements
            select String.Format("name: {0}" + Environment.NewLine + "address: {1}",  // Format the boom item
                                 boomElement.Element("name").Value,  // Gets the name value of the boom element
                                 boomElement.Element("address").Value);  // Gets the address value of the boom element

var result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, booms);  // Concatenates all boom items into one string with
```

### Update

To generalize it with any elements in `boom`, the idea is the same.

```
var booms = from boomElement in document.Descendants("boom")  // Go through the collection of boom elements
            let boolChildren = (from boomElementChild in boomElement.Elements()  // Go through the collection of elements in the boom element
                                select String.Format("{0}: {1}",  // Formats the name of the element and its value
                                                     boomElementChild.Name.LocalName,  // Name of the element
                                                     boomElementChild.Value))  // Value of the element
            select String.Join(Environment.NewLine, boolChildren);  // Concatenate the formated child elements
```

The first and last lines remains the same.

Comment: Can you generalize this to "loop" through the elements within "boom" (not assuming the fixed "name" and "address")?

Comment: Thanks, that works. Can you add another update that allows me to filter out boom elements satisfying some arbitrary condition, e.g. where `address` contains "New" (in this case only "New York City", and only the first boom would show up)?

Comment: I created a separate question for this, feel free to take a shot at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815090/adding-a-condition-filter-to-this-linq-code