# XML reading repeating child elements with same name as parent c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have xml in format below:

```
<rows>
   <rows>
      <primitiveValue>000</primitiveValue>
   </rows>
   <rows>
      <primitiveValue>58316</primitiveValue>
   </rows>
   <rows>
   <primitiveValue>133083.0</primitiveValue>
   </rows>
</rows>
<rows>
  <rows>
    <primitiveValue>001</primitiveValue>
  </rows>
  <rows>
    <primitiveValue>66018</primitiveValue>
  </rows>
  <rows>
    <primitiveValue>172546.0</primitiveValue>
  </rows>
</rows>
```

I need to split the data per parent element of rows, but don't know how to do this.

I've tried the code below, but this loops through every instance of rows and causes duplication.

```
        string Values = "";

        foreach (XElement element in xDoc.Descendants("rows"))
        {

            foreach (XElement childElement in element.Descendants("rows").Elements("primitiveValue"))
            {

                Values = Values + "," + childElement.Value.ToString();

            }


        }
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Can you change the xml at all? If so, it would behoove you to make it `<rows><row/><row/></rows>` instead of calling everything rows.

Comment: nah i can't as it comes from a google analytics api. it is returned automatically in JSON and then i convert it to XML as I want to use a process i have already set up to import xml per row into a SQL Server DB

Comment: If that is the case, I suggest you look into [JSON.net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/814001/299327) for converting from JSON to XML rather than rolling your own.

Comment: i've already used JSON.net to convert it from JSON to this in XML. That above fragment part of the converted XML document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple with `System.Xml.XPath.Extensions`:

```
var values = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(@"//rows/rows/primitiveValue").Select(v => (double)v);
string result = String.Join(",", values);
```

Values will be `IEnumerable<double>` containing values of primitiveValue elements. And result will be concatenated string of all values. BTW you are missing root element in your xml.

UPDATE

```
IEnumerable<string> result = 
             xdoc.Root.Elements("rows")
                 .Select(r => String.Join(",", r.Descendants("primitiveValue")
                                                .Select(v => (double)v)));
```

This will return sequence of strings, each of string will contain concatenated values of inner rows. If you need raw strings instead of double values, then cast value nodes to string.

Comment: i need to split the primitivevalues into rows though
In this example there are 3 values per row. I working on an automated process where the number of values per row will vary also

Comment: @AlistairMcIntyre sorry, didn't get what you are trying to do. With your sample xml this code returns string with all values `0,58316,133083,1,66018,172546`

Answer (score 1):

Descendants will find all nodes with the name that you are looking for regardless of how far down the XML tree that they are. Try experimenting with something like this:

```
foreach (XElement element in xDoc.Children("rows"))
        {
            foreach (XElement childElement in element.Descendants("rows").Elements("primitiveValue"))
            {
                Values = Values + "," + childElement.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

The key is that using Children should only return nodes that are directly below the root element as opposed to searching the entire structure of the XML document for matching elements.

Comment: thanks. i cant locate the xdocument children method though. Am i missing a namespace or something else?