# How to Json To Xml

Tags: c#, xml, json

I am new for Json and I have a simple problem.

I am trying to convert json file to xml file with c#. But it throw an exception.

The Code is ;

```
  private void TakeXML()
    {
        string json = ReadText();

        XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);

        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("json.xml", null);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        doc.Save(writer);
    }
```

The ReadText function is;

```
 private string ReadText()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Sinan\Desktop\bina.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        string json;
        try
        {
            json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return json;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {

            sr.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

for `XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);` line, it said that;

"JSON root object has multiple properties. The root object must have a single property in order to create a valid XML document. Consider specifing a DeserializeRootElementName."

I am searching to solve this problem but ı haven't found it. İf you help me in this regard, I will be glad. Thank you.

Comment: Create a datatable from xml and then there ara various ways to get json from datatable.

Comment: My need is 'converting Json to Xml'. Not 'converting Xml to Json'.

Comment: Sorry for the misundestaunding, use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/how-to-convert-json-to-datatable-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In method `DeserializeXmlNode` specify the root node name in second parameter as shown in below code:

```
XmlDocument doc =
  (XmlDocument)
     Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "rootNodeName");
                                                   // second parameter
```

Although if you can give json string then it would be easy to give exact answer.

Reference link: [Converting JSON to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16562355/468718)