# How can I get a response from a url in XML instead of JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, json

I am trying to access a website using C# and HttpWebRequest. I can get the response from the website but the response is in JSON. Is there any way to get the response in XML instead of JSON so I can use XmlDocument to parse through the information? I was asked to use XML instead of JSON...

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Are you using a Third-Party URL ?

Comment: You could specify in the HEADER of the Http request the Resopnse's format as xml, provided the server supports that. OR you may convert the JSON to XML by serializations

Comment: Does the server support returning data in Xml at all?

Comment: yea, I'm using a third-party url...

Comment: I'm not sure, I think it only supports JSON

Comment: @josh4263  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562101/converting-json-to-xml

Answer (score 0):

No.what kind of response format all depends on the website. you just can follow the  response format to make your logic

Comment: I can only get the response in JSON and for some reason, I am asked to utilize XML... So would I have to use JavaScript in order to DeSerialize the JSON string? (It's my first time doing JSON and accessing information from a website so I am lost...)

Comment: So I still haven't figured this out... I am trying to get information from spotify so api.spotify.com can you get xml from there?