# C# NewtonSoft JsonConvert serializexmlnode to nested array?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Default behaviour of JSON to XML serialization is arrays elements appear on the same level as non-array elements. Like on example from https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertJsonToXml.htm :

```
 {
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
    'User',
    'Admin'
  ]
 }
```

is serialised into

```
<Root>
   <Email>james@example.com</Email>
   <Active>true</Active>
   <CreatedDate>2013-01-20T00:00:00Z</CreatedDate>
   <Roles>User</Roles>
   <Roles>Admin</Roles>
</Root>
```

But I need XML array in the form

```
<Roles>
  <Item>User</Item>
  <Item>Admin</Item>
</Roles>
```

How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit the code into the question please? And as for question, is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38726166/1997232) helpful?

Comment: Interesting! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No problem!

```
var source = "(your JSON");
dynamic roles = JObject.Parse(source).Roles;
```

Following this, you may re-serialize roles to XML, achieving the desired result.

Comment: Interesting! I'll try and let you know