# Crash after serializing JObject with DataContractSerializer and XmlDictionaryWriter

Tags: c#, json.net, datacontractserializer

I have to serialize an Newtonsoft JObject with DataContractSerializer, it crashes with stack overflow.
How to make it work?
My code is.

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(JObject));
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
var writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(stream1);
var obj = new JObject();
serializer.WriteObject(writer, obj);
writer.Flush();
```

The following example is converting JObject to common type using [`ISerializationSurrogateProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogateprovider?view=net-5.0) functionality. It will crash with stack overflow.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

class Program
{
    [DataContract(Name = "JTokenReference", Namespace = "urn:actors")]
    [Serializable]
    public sealed class JTokenReference
    {
        public JTokenReference()
        {
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "JType", Order = 0, IsRequired = true)]
        public JTokenType JType { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Value", Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public static JTokenReference From(JToken jt)
        {
            if (jt == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return new JTokenReference()
            {
                Value = jt.ToString(),
                JType = jt.Type
            };
        }
        public object To()
        {
            switch (JType)
            {
                case JTokenType.Object:
                    {
                        return JObject.Parse(Value);
                    }
                case JTokenType.Array:
                    {
                        return JArray.Parse(Value);
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        return JToken.Parse(Value);
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    internal class ActorDataContractSurrogate : ISerializationSurrogateProvider
    {
        public static readonly ISerializationSurrogateProvider Instance = new ActorDataContractSurrogate();

        public Type GetSurrogateType(Type type)
        {
            if (typeof(JToken).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                return typeof(JTokenReference);
            }

            return type;
        }

        public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else if (obj is JToken jt)
            {
                return JTokenReference.From(jt);
            }

            return obj;
        }

        public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else if (obj is JTokenReference reference &&
                    typeof(JToken).IsAssignableFrom(targetType))
            {
                return reference.To();
            }
            return obj;
        }
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Test", Namespace = "urn:actors")]
    [Serializable]
    public class Test
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "obj", Order = 0, IsRequired = false)]
        public JObject obj;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Test),
        new DataContractSerializerSettings()
        {
            MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue,
            KnownTypes = new Type[] { typeof(JTokenReference), typeof(JObject), typeof(JToken) },
        });

        serializer.SetSerializationSurrogateProvider(ActorDataContractSurrogate.Instance);

        MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(stream1);
        var obj = new JObject();
        var test = new Test()
        {
            obj = obj,
        };
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, test);
        writer.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream1.GetBuffer(), 0, checked((int)stream1.Length)));
    }
}
```

I am trying to define a new type JTokenReference to replace JObject/JToken when serializing, but it crashed before replace happens. It seems it failed to resolve the type.

Comment: I would suggest you first convert the `JObject` into standard .NET types using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19140420/10263), then you can serialize that result using the `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: Why are you trying to serialize a `JObject` with `DataContractSerializer`?  A `JObject` is the JSON document object model of Json.NET, there is no reason to imagine it could be serialized to XML by `DataContractSerializer`.   If you just need to convert JSON to XML, see [How to convert JSON to XML or XML to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/814001/3744182).  If you have already parsed to a `JObject` you can use `JsonExtension.ToXElement()` from [How to generate XML from JSON with parent node of array items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38731234/3744182) to convert it to XML.

Comment: I used ISerializationSurrogateProvider to convert it to a .NET types, but it crashed too with the same reason.

Comment: The 3rd-party framework converts every parameter to XML, and unfortunately my parameter is a json.net object. I have no choice, so how to work around this?

Comment: *ISerializationSurrogateProvider to convert it to a .NET types, but it crashed too with the same reason.* - then can you please share a [mcve] with JSON and code that reproduce the problem?  Also, was it a **crash**, or an **exception**?  If the latter, please also share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any.

Comment: I edited my question and put my test code to produce the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Your approach is reasonable, and ought to work, but fails due to what seems to be a bug in the [`ISerializationSurrogateProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogateprovider?view=net-5.0) functionality with recursive collection types.  You're going to need to change your design to use surrogate properties whenever you need to serialize a `JToken`, e.g. as follows:

```
[IgnoreDataMember]
public JObject obj { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "obj", Order = 0, IsRequired = false)]
string objSurrogate { get { return obj?.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None); } set { obj = (value == null ? null : JObject.Parse(value)); } }
```

**Explanation**

The crash you are experiencing is a stack overflow, and can be reproduced more simply as follows.  When the data contract serializer writes a generic such as `List<string>`, it constructs a [data contract name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-names) by combining the generic class and parameter names like so:

- `List<string>`: `ArrayOfstring`
- `List<List<string>`: `ArrayOfArrayOfstring`
- `List<List<List<string>>>`: `ArrayOfArrayOfArrayOfstring`

And so on.  As the generic nesting gets deeper the name gets longer.  Well then, what happens if we define a self-recursive collection type like the following?

```
public class RecursiveList<T> : List<RecursiveList<T>>
{
}
```

Well, if we try to serialize one of these list with the data contract serializer, **it crashes with a stack overflow exception** trying to figure out the contract name.  Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QuRJ96) -- you will need to uncomment the line `//Test(new RecursiveList<string>());` to see the crash:

```
Stack overflow.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.QCallModule, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle[], System.RuntimeTypeHandle[])
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32, System.Type[], System.Type[])
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(System.Reflection.MetadataToken, System.Reflection.MetadataImport ByRef, System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, System.Reflection.MetadataToken, System.RuntimeType, Boolean, ListBuilder`1<System.Object> ByRef, System.RuntimeType ByRef, System.IRuntimeMethodInfo ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsCustomAttributeDefined(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, System.RuntimeType, Int32, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsDefined(System.RuntimeType, System.RuntimeType, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.IsCollectionOrTryCreate(System.Type, Boolean, System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract ByRef, System.Type ByRef, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.IsCollectionHelper(System.Type, System.Type ByRef, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetNonDCTypeStableName(System.Type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(System.Type, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetCollectionStableName(System.Type, System.Type, System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetNonDCTypeStableName(System.Type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(System.Type, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetCollectionStableName(System.Type, System.Type, System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetNonDCTypeStableName(System.Type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(System.Type, Boolean ByRef)
```

Oops.  Well, what if we create a serialization surrogate such as the following dummy surrogate for `RecursiveList<string>`

```
public class RecursiveListStringSurrogate
{
    // A dummy surrogate that serializes nothing, for testing purposes.
}

public class RecursiveListStringSurrogateSelector : ISerializationSurrogateProvider
{
    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj is RecursiveListStringSurrogate)
            return new RecursiveList<string>();
        return obj;
    }

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj is RecursiveList<string>)
            return new RecursiveListStringSurrogate();
        return obj;
    }

    public Type GetSurrogateType(Type type) 
    {
        if (type == typeof(RecursiveList<string>))
            return typeof(RecursiveListStringSurrogate);
        return type;
    }
}
```

Using that surrogate, an empty `new RecursiveList<string>()` can indeed be serialized successfully, as

```xml
<RecursiveListStringSurrogate xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" />
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9azy4O).

OK, now let's try using the surrogate when a `RecursiveList<string>` is embedded in a model such as:

```
public class Model
{
    public RecursiveList<string> List { get; set; }
}
```

Well when I try to serialize an instance of this model with an empty list, **the crash comes back**.  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2whhXA) - you will need to uncomment the line `//Test(new Model { List = new RecursiveList<string>() });` to see the crash.

Oops again.  It's not entirely clear why this fails.  I can only speculate that, somewhere, Microsoft is keeping a dictionary mapping original data contract names to surrogate data contract names -- which causes a stack overflow simply generating a dictionary key.

Now what does this have to do with `JObject` and your `Test` class?  Well it turns out that [`JObject`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs) is another example of a recursive collection type.  It implements `IDictionary<string, JToken?>` and [`JToken`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs) in turn implements `IEnumerable<JToken>` thereby triggering the same stack overflow we saw with the simple model containing a `RecursiveList<string>`.

You might even want to [report an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+datacontractserializer) to Microsoft about this (though I don't know whether they are fixing bugs with the data contract serializer any more.)

**Workaround**

To avoid this issue, you will need to modify your model(s) to use surrogate properties for `JToken` members as shown at the beginning of this answer:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Test", Namespace = "urn:actors")]
public class Test
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public JObject obj { get; set; }
    
    [DataMember(Name = "obj", Order = 0, IsRequired = false)]
    string objSurrogate { get { return obj?.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None); } set { obj = (value == null ? null : JObject.Parse(value)); } }
}
```

Which can be serialized successfully as follows:

```
var obj = new JObject();
var test = new Test()
{
    obj = obj,
};

var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(test.GetType());

MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
var writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(stream1);
serializer.WriteObject(writer, test);
writer.Flush();
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream1.GetBuffer(), 0, checked((int)stream1.Length)));
```

Notes:

- If you need to serialize a `JToken` as the *root object* you can either wrap it in some container object, or use the `ActorDataContractSurrogate` from your question.  As we have seen, the serialization functionality does seem to work for recursive collection types when they are the root object.
- Since you are serializing to binary, for efficiency I suggest formatting the `JObject` with `Formatting.None`.
- The surrogate property can be private as long as it is marked with `[DataMember]`.

Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uUq7MH).

Comment: Thank you for the very smart solution!