# Convert JSON to XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml, json

I know how to do this but what I don't know is how I handle JSON like this:

```js
[{
    "player": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Name",
        "contact": {
            "tel": "123456789",
            "nick_name": "NickName"
        },
        "achievments": {
            "achievment1": "Achievment",
            "achievment2": "Achievment"
        }
    }
}]
```

"contact" and "achievments" have subinfo. How do I handle this?

```cs
 XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                new XElement("Players", from player in PlayerList
                                        select new XElement("player",
                                               new XElement("id", player.Id),
                                               new XElement("name", player.Name))));
```

Comment: Do you want to convert JSON to XML or what's the problem?

Comment: Well in my code i write the JSON data into "PlayerList" and the value of that list i want to write out into a local XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

It has methods for converting directly from Json to xml, and does parsing very well too. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/convert-json-string-to-xml-or-xml-to-json-string) for more

Comment: Yes ok, but i can't use "DeserializeXmlNode".