# How to convert string xml to json in c# and send over SOAP in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, soap-client

How to convert xml data into JSON format. I want to send it over the SOAP, too.

Could you provide some example?

Comment: It looks like 2 different questions to me, one about  conversion from XML to JSON format, the other one is about C# library for SOAP usage. It would be better if you concentrate your question and show what have you already tried.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use JsonConvert class to convert.

here is the code

```
 // To convert an XML node contained in string xml into a JSON string   
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

    // To convert JSON text contained in string json into an XML node
    XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
```

The above code is from here [How to convert JSON to XML or XML to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/convert-json-string-to-xml-or-xml-to-json-string)

For sending data through soap [Client to send SOAP request and received response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-received-response)

Comment: thnx Alex its work for me