# can not covert json to xml

Tags: c#, json, xml

i am trying to convert json string to xml
1) my json is

```
[  
       {  
          "QuizTitle":"asdf",
          "QuizImage":"",
          "QuizCategory":"0",
          "QuizTags":"asdf",
          "question":[  
             [  
                {  
                   "QuestionType":"1",
                   "QuestionTitle":"asdf",
                   "questionOption":[  
                      {  
                         "QuestionOptionValue":"sdf",
                         "QuestionOptionIsRight":"0"
                      },
                      {  
                         "QuestionOptionValue":"asdf",
                         "QuestionOptionIsRight":"1"
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ],
             [  
                {  
                   "QuestionType":"2",
                   "QuestionTitle":"sdfdsf",
                   "questionOption":[  
                      {  
                         "QuestionOptionValue":"asdf",
                         "QuestionOptionIsRight":"0"
                      },
                      {  
                         "QuestionOptionValue":"asdf",
                         "QuestionOptionIsRight":"1"
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ]
          ]
       }
    ]
```

2) my c# code is

```
XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(str);
```

Getting following error:

> Error:--XmlNodeConverter can only convert JSON that begins with an
>   object.

i tried to little edit in `json` like `remove []` for question element. but not worked.

Comment: did u tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(str,"root");`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json-by-using-json-net

Comment: Try removing the outermost [].

Comment: yes JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(str,"root"); worked for me , thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [Mitchell Skurnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83250/mitchell-skurnik)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json#comment45419014_816095), you can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(JSONString, "root");`.

> If your data is an array then you need to do something like this: JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{"Row":" + json + "}", "root").ToXmlString() otherwise you will get a "XmlNodeConverter can only convert JSON that begins with an object." exception.
>
> – Mitchell Skurnik
>
> Feb 17 '15 at 1:11

Comment: I tried JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{\"Row\":" + json + "}", "root").ToXmlString(); worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre> public static string GetXMLFromJson(string jsonString)
        {
             string parentNote="Person";
            XDocument doc = (XDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode("{\""+ parentNote + "\":" + json + "}", "DocumentElement");
            return doc.ToString();
        } </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works when there is only one value in an array. This does not support multiple arrays on the parent node.