# Json.Net Serialize Complex Object to Xml Attribute And Value

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

Let's say I have a Json object that looks like this:

```
{
    "Phones": [
        {
            "Phone": {
                "Value": 123,
                "@Type": "Foo"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to call `JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode()` but would like the resulting XML to look like this:

```
<Phones>
    <Phone Type="Foo">123</Phone>
</Phones>
```

Currently `Value` is being deserialized to an xml element as a child of `Phone`, but I want it to be the XML value of `Phone`. Is there a way to do this using Json.Net, like a special operator that tells it to deserialize it as such, without having to create a custom serializer? Any help is apppreciated.

Comment: May be related to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out. using

```
"Phone": {
      "@Type": "Foo",
      "#text": 123
 }
```

gives me the expected result. `#text` tells it not to create a child element for that value.