# c# - Object with serialized object key as part of object

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serialization

Currently in our project we have a certain class which has a String description.
Furthermore we have an object.

```
Object Foo { 
    Apple: {parts: 5},
    Description:  theproblematicobject,
    ,,,, 
}
```

Description is set up as a type string. Thus the object needs to be serialized to be assigned as the value of the description.

At the end we return foo as a JSONConvert.serializer(foo).
Upon recieve, object foo is nicely formatted `JSON`, but the description is still a serialized string.

Is there a combinations of functions I can use how I can serialize the problematic object (so it fits the string type) and upon deserialization on request, it becomes one nicely formatted json instead of.

**Result**:

```
"Name": "Friday, 21 October 2016 New...",
  "Description": "{\"HoursList\":[],\"EmployeeFullname\":\"..........",
  "SwipeLeftAction": null,
  "SwipeLeftDescription": null,
  "SwipeLeftColor": null,
  "SwipeRightAction": null,
  "SwipeRightDescription": null,
  "SwipeRightColor": null,
  "ClickAction": "uiweb/em......."
}
```

**Desired**:

```
"Name": "Friday, 21 October 2016 New...",
  "Description": {"HoursList":[],
                  "EmployeeFullname" : ".........."
                 }
  "SwipeLeftAction": null,
  "SwipeLeftDescription": null,
  "SwipeLeftColor": null,
  "SwipeRightAction": null,
  "SwipeRightDescription": null,
  "SwipeRightColor": null,
  "ClickAction": "uiweb/em......."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `description` is a string. You can clearly see that from the JSON itself. That means you get back a string from any automatic deserializer.

If you want an object out of it, run a second JSON deserializer pass yourself on the description field.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, you have any formatter or something other logic that do the wrong serialization. What library version do you use?

The latest [JsonConvert.SerializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/m_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert_serializeobject.htm) works well.

Here is a little example:

```
private class Foo
{
    public int Apple { get; set; }
    public Description Description { get; set; }
}

private class Description
{
    public int[] HoursList { get; set; }
}


var a = new Foo
{
    Apple = 1,
    Description = new Description
    {
        HoursList = new[] {1}
    }
};

var b = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
```

The result is a well formatted json string:

```
{"Apple":1,"Description":{"HoursList":[1]}}
```

Comment: foo.Description is of the type String (and we cant change it without breaking other stuff)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Serialize the problematic object to an XML string instead of JSON as shown here:
[Serialize an object to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml)

Convert XML to JSON as shown here:
[How to convert JSON to XML or XML to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json)

Comment: Awesome - hope it helps!