# JSON to XML class conversions

Tags: c#, json, xml, linq, class

I cannot seem to line up the class of the Json into Linq XML.

The `c.first`, `c.second` and the `c.third` are highlighted and states:

> "Are you missing a using directive or assembly reference."

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json1 = "[count:[place:{first:1,second:2,third:3}],[place:{first:11,second:22,third:33}],[place:{first:111,second:222,third:333}]]]";
var jsons = serializer.Serialize(json1);
var jsona = serializer.Deserialize<List<jClass>>(jsons);
var xmld = new XDocument(
    new XElement("count", jsona.Select(c =>
        new XElement("place",
            new XElement("first", c.first),
            new XElement("second", c.second),
            new XElement("third", c.third)
        )
    ))
);
```

Class.cs

```
public class jClass
{
    public jNumber[] count { get; set; }
}
public class jNumber
{
    public jTopThree[] place { get; set; }
}
public class jTopThree
{
    public int first { get; set; }
    public int second { get; set; }
    public int third { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `c` is of the type `jClass` which only contains the property `count` which is an array of `jNumber`. Which value were you actually trying to pick? 1? 22? 333?

Comment: How do you equate the jTopThree so all the firsts,seconds and thirds in the xml document being created?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out what your JSON should look like. Do you have an example of the desired XML?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your object structure is essentially an array of array of arrays and you're only doing one Select. Where you're building your xml, your `c` variable is at the `jClass` level, so you're trying to read the `first`, `second` and `third` properties from that.

It's unclear what your xml structure should be, but you're either going to need to use a couple more `.Select` calls to drill down further to the jTopThree instances, use `.SelectMany` to flatten it out, or change your object definitions up a bit.

Comment: I need two more ".Select" They need tiered down for each class heading What do you put in front of second and third ".Select" to represent the respective classes?

Comment: Do you have an example of the XML that you're trying to output?

Answer (score 0):

json text and object structure seems to be invalid. you can try some like  this..

object structure

```
public class jClass
{
    public jTopThree[] count { get; set; }
}
public class jTopThree
{
    public int first { get; set; }
    public int second { get; set; }
    public int third { get; set; }
}
```

serialization

```
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json1 = "{count:[{first:1,second:2,third:3},{first:11,second:22,third:33},{first:111,second:222,third:333}]}";
        var obj = serializer.Deserialize<jClass>(json1);
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(jClass));
        string xmlString;
        using (System.IO.StringWriter sww = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
                xmlString = sww.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am trying to make the whole xml String Document.  <count><place><first>1</first><second>2</second>...</place></count>.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var json1 = "[{\"place\":{\"first\":1,\"second\":2,\"third\":3}},{\"place\":{\"first\":11,\"second\":22,\"third\":33}},{\"place\":{\"first\":111,\"second\":222,\"third\":333}}]";
        XmlDocument deserializeXmlNode;
        if (json1.IndexOf("[", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            deserializeXmlNode = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode($"{{\"items\":{json1}}}", "source");
        }
        else
        {
            deserializeXmlNode = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json1, "source");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(deserializeXmlNode.OuterXml);
```

If you want just copy to XML and can afford Nugget package, go for Newtonsoft.Json and modify the code above to suite your needs. I have slighlty changed the input json, because it was not valid per http://www.json.org/ . It should work with any valid JSON though.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm

[How to convert JSON to XML or XML to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json)

Answer (score 0):

So firstly your JSON is formatted badly, based on your example I think it should look like this (to me having "place" seems redundant but I've left it for now):

> {
>   "count": [
>   {"place": [
>   {"first":1,"second":2,"third":3}]},
>   {"place": [
>   {"first":11,"second":22,"third":33}]},
>   {"place": [
>   {"first":111,"second":222,"third":333}]}
>   ]
>   }

Your classes should look like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Count> count { get; set; }
}

public class Count
{
    public List<Place> place { get; set; }
}

public class Place
{
    public int first { get; set; }
    public int second { get; set; }
    public int third { get; set; }
}
```

Lastly you can create XML this way:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = "your json string";
var result= serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
var xmld = new XDocument(
           new XElement("count", result.count
               .SelectMany(p => p.place)
               .Select(x => 
                   new XElement("place",
                       new XElement("first", x.first),
                       new XElement("second", x.second),
                       new XElement("third", x.third)
                   )
                ))
           );
```

Output:

```
<count>
  <place>
    <first>1</first>
    <second>2</second>
    <third>3</third>
  </place>
  <place>
    <first>11</first>
    <second>22</second>
    <third>33</third>
  </place>
  <place>
    <first>111</first>
    <second>222</second>
    <third>333</third>
  </place>
</count>
```

Comment: result.count.Select(c => c)
 .SelectMany(p => p.place)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you meant, but yes the extra select was redundant so I've removed it. Result is the same.