# Json with Nested Objects and each are differently named

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a json object that is coming from an endpoint.

```
{
"user_info": {
    "myapp1": {
      "roles": [
        "requestor"
      ]
    },
    "myapp2": {
      "roles": [
        "requests-edit",
        "requests-view"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Based on this structure its pretty clear that there are two strongly typed objects. `user_info` and `roles`. However, the apps `(myapp1, myapp2, account)` are not in an array, they are "dynamic" or "anonymous" objects.

What is the recommended way to get the roles with a known app name?

EG, some pseudo code.

```
// returns the sub objects as a dictionary of <string, Roles>;
var anonjson = JsonAnon.DeserializeOnProperty<string, Roles>("user_info");
var roles = anonjson.Where(x => x.Key.Value == "myapp2").FirstOrDefault();
// i forget what dictionaries use to get by key I put x.Key, this could be invalid.
```

Comment: Have you considered `converting` the JSON into an `Xml` document and then use an `xpath query`? See [How To Convert Json To Xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I suggest creating 2 classes for Deserialization

```
    public class UserInfo
    {
        [JsonProperty("user_info")]
        public Dictionary<string, Account> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class Account
    {
        [JsonProperty("roles")]
        public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

The deserialization could then look like this

```
        var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(jsonString);
        var allRoles = info.Users.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Roles);
```

The examle uses the Newtonsoft package

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what [@OwnBlood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58651161/json-with-nested-objects-and-each-are-differently-named/58651432#58651432) suggested, you can make two classes using the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) framework:

```
public class Application
{
    [JsonProperty("roles")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("user_info")]
    public IDictionary<string, Application> UserInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize with the  
[JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) method:

```
var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonString);
```

And you can create a method that filters out the roles from a specific application name using LINQ:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetUserApplicationRoles(string applicationName, User data) => 
    data.UserInfo
        .TryGetValue(applicationName, out var value) ?
            value.Roles : 
            Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

**Explanation:**

- Since `UserInfo` is a `IDictionary<string, Application>`, we can use [`TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8) to access the specific `applicationName`. This allows O(1) access.
- Then we can simply return the `IEnumerable<string>` roles, or an empty collection, in this case `Enumerable.Empty<string>`.

Working demo found at [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MSjwEi)