# How to convert MessageEnvelope xmlns to json

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have integrated with internal API and the response comes in XML format which I want it to be in JSON format. All I want is to convert the returned API results to JSON and then do the mapping.

How can I convert XML to JSON and do the mapping?

```
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            const string BaseUrl = "myUrl";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

            HttpResponseMessage odsResponse = await client.GetAsync("api method i am consuming");

            //trying to convert xml to json
            var xx = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(odsResponse, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

            //this null is returning null
            Viewmodel.AccountLiteExt acc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Viewmodel.AccountLiteExt>(xx);

            if (odsResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                xx = odsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(xx);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

XML API Response. I have formatted it online and cut it as it is a big file.

```
 {
"MessageEnvelope": {
    "AccountLite": {
        "AccountLiteExt": [
            {
                "Id": "1",
                "Status": "Active",
                "Type": "Bil",
                "CSN": "1",
                "Location": "ZIM",
                "MasterAccountId": "1",
                "Name": "Test"
            },
            {
                "Id": "2",
                "Status": "Active",
                "Type": "Bil",
                "CSN": "2",
                "Location": "ZIM",
                "MasterAccountId": "2",
                "Name": "Test"
            },
        ],
        "_xmlns": "Url"
    },
    "_xmlns": "Url"
}
}
```

Converted it to C# classes for data mapping

```
    public class AccountLiteExt    {
    public string Id { get; set; } 
    public string Status { get; set; } 
    public string Type { get; set; } 
    public string CSN { get; set; } 
    public string Location { get; set; } 
    public string MasterAccountId { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}

public class AccountLite    {
    public List<AccountLiteExt> AccountLiteExt { get; set; } 
    public string _xmlns { get; set; } 
}

public class MessageEnvelope    {
    public AccountLite AccountLite { get; set; } 
    public string _xmlns { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public MessageEnvelope MessageEnvelope { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: This was already ask before, you can check it here [How to convert JSON to XML or XML to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814027/8795884).

Answer (score 1):

Had found the solution by first creating an instance of XmlDocument, after that, I had to convert to JSON and then SerializeXmlNode and DeserializeObject.

```
            var xml = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
            Model model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);
```