# Dynamics 365 Plugin parse Note attachment XML without using file

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, powerapps, power-automate

In Dynamics CRM online, I have a record in the annotation entity which has an XML attached.
From a plugin, I need to get the content of that attachment and create an XML element so I can deserialize its content as an object class and apply some logic.

As we are in an online implementation, I cannot do things like create a file and read its content.
So what we have is a document content in the attached file, which is a string with multiple characters, as you can see here (attachment is generated by a Power Automate flow):

[image]

Here is some of my code:

```
            byte[] fileContentBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(note.DocumentBody);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(fileContentBytes);

            StreamReader globalReader = new StreamReader(stream);

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            doc.Load(globalReader);
```

The error message says that `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1`, as it's trying to parse as an XML something that is not parse-able as that.

Comment: Any follow up questions ?

Answer (score 1):

The document body is base 64 encoded.

Try the following

```
byte[] fileContentBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(note.DocumentBody);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(fileContentBytes);

StreamReader globalReader = new StreamReader(stream);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load(globalReader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Power Automate is generating JSON document, you are trying to parse it as XML, so failing.

Instead [try some methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json) to convert to your needed format.

[image]