# Dynamics 365 BC - Add Purchase Invoice attachment and note using API

Tags: dynamics-business-central

We manipulate purchase data in Dynamics 365 BC using API to update, receive and invoice PO lines.
([Dynamics 365 Plugin parse Note attachment XML without using file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67741741/dynamics-365-plugin-parse-note-attachment-xml-without-using-file))
We now want to upload an invoice document as an attachment to purchase invoice and add/update attachment notes using API.
We did not find any documented API to do that.

We've looked at the attachement API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/resources/dynamics_attachment
but it never return values:

Call example: `{{baseUrl}}/companies({{companyId}})/attachments?$filter=parentId eq bf4eb7ea-d558-ec11-bb7c-000d3a2b9aee and parentType eq 'Purchase Invoice'`

Always returns:

```
{
   "@odata.context": "api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.../$metadata
   "value": []
}
```

but this Purchase Invoice is valid and has attachment (not found in attachment table **but in 'Document Attachment' table**)
And no idea on how to get 'Attachment Notes'

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated !
Thanks,
Vincent

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I updated the question with add info

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm also trying to retrieve/update notes inside the Fact table side pane

Comment: https://joshanglesea.wordpress.com/2021/01/25/business-central-attachmentsapi/

Answer (score 1):

the APIs mentioned are not implemented in Business Central at this time.

If you think this would be a great improvement to the product itself it's greatly appreciated if you submit an idea at https://aka.ms/bcideas. If you've done so, please link the idea in your question. Thanks in advance.

At this point, you would need to add the custom APIs yourself, including one for the "Record Links" and another for the "Document Attachment" source table. An example for the "notes" could look like this:

```
page 50100 "API - Notes"
{
    PageType = API;
    APIPublisher = 'publisher';
    APIGroup = 'group';
    APIVersion = 'v1.0';
    EntityName = 'note';
    EntitySetName = 'notes';
    DelayedInsert = true;
    SourceTable = "Record Link";
    ODataKeyFields = SystemId;

    layout
    {
        area(Content)
        {
            group(records)
            {
                field(id; Rec.SystemId) { }
                field(linkID; Rec."Link ID") { }
                field(recordID; Rec."Record ID") { }
                field(note; Rec.Note) { }
                field(lastModifiedDateTime; Rec.SystemModifiedAt) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: you might want to look at the powerful **SBI Data Braider** extension: https://sparebrained.com/appsource/databraider/. A great solution to bypass the need to create and customize APIs yourself via AL code. All this is managed via the web client.

If this question is still relevant, I would also like to follow up with an example of the "Document Attachment" scenario.