# How to convert huge XML files to JSON in a multi-user concurrency environment without saturating RAM?

Tags: c#, .net-core, server, multi-user, xml-to-json

I am facing the problem with converting XML file to JSON with following code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Start");

string inputPath = "input.xml";

// Load XML document
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(inputPath);

string outputPath = "output.json";
File.WriteAllText(outputPath, JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc));

Console.Write("End");

Console.ReadKey();
```

The file fills memory and that's problem. I didn't find solution without fill RAM.

How can I accomplish that? Thank you very much

Comment: How big is the XML file?

Comment: I need convert unknown json files on server, so performance is very important. I didn't find the solution on link what you sent.

Comment: I am looking for solution with XmlReader or something like that.

Comment: What do you call a "*huge*" file? What size? How can that fill the memory? What memory? You should also take into consideration that XML and JSON are not for example CSV and the format can vary from compact to stretched like HTML and CS for example, so you can't read line by line... in a pinch you could read the file byte by byte and determine tags, if no component already exists, maybe, I don't know, I haven't searched the web or https://nugetmusthaves.com/ and https://github.com/

Comment: It can be up to 1 GB and I need convert many files at same time (it depends on users of my app). My solution above fills RAM and that's not a way to do that.

Comment: I need to convert many files for my users. Could you imagine convert 1 GB file for 1000 users at the same time? It require 1000 GB of RAM. It's insane! It's not acceptable

Comment: Ok, I see, you are on a webserver or a mainframe that support 1000 requests at a time? I don't know XmlReader nor if it can match, thus see for example https://zetcode.com/csharp/xmlreader/ and https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/reading-xml-with-the-xmlreader-class/

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json/50118541#50118541